# How does this bitwise operation check for a power of 2?

Tags: c, math, bit-manipulation

I'm looking at some code which should be trivial -- but my math is failing me miserably here.

Here's a condition that checks if a number if a power of 2 using the following:

```
if((num != 1) && (num & (num - 1))) { /* make num pow of 2 */ }
```

My question is, how does using a bitwise AND between num and num - 1 determine if a number is a power of 2?

Comment: More information can be found at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2

Comment: It obviously depends on the type of `num` - most of the answers here assume it's an unsigned integral type, where the bitwise operations are well-defined.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Any power of 2 minus 1 is all ones: (*2 <sup><sup>**N**</sup></sup> - 1 = 111....b*)

```
2 = 2^1.  2-1 = 1 (1b)
4 = 2^2.  4-1 = 3 (11b)
8 = 2^3.  8-1 = 7 (111b)
```

Take 8 for example.  1000 & 0111 = 0000

So that expression tests if a number is NOT a power of 2.

Comment: corner case when 1.num=0 and num = -2147483648 if data type is int limited by min value.
when num==0, num is not 2 power

Comment: How does this explanation prove anything? It merely shows that a power of 2 would produce `0` for the expression `x & (x - 1)`, not the other way around.

Comment: Late, I know, but this answer lacks explanation of the counter-case...

Answer (score 19):

Well, the first case will check for 2<sup>0</sup> == 1.

For the other cases the `num & (num - 1)` comes into play:

That's saying if you take any number, and mask off the bits from one lower, you'll get one of two cases:

1. if the number is a power of two already, then one less will result in a binary number that only has the lower-order bits set.  Using `&` there will do nothing.

   - Example with 8: `0100 & (0100 - 1)` --> `(0100 & 0011)` --> `0000`
2. if the number is not a power of two already, then one less will not touch the highest bit, so the result will be *at least* the largest power of two less than num.

   - Example with 3: `0011 & (0011 - 1)` --> `(0011 & 0010)` --> `0010`
   - Example with 13: `1101 & (1101 - 1)` --> `(1101 & 1100)` --> `1100`

So the actual expression finds everything that isn't a power of two, including 2<sup>0</sup>.

Comment: Actually, the check for the special case `num==1` (2^0=1) is not needed. For this case (num & (num-1)) = (1 & 0) = 0 anyway.

Comment: The explanation of the second point is incorrect, (num - 1) might be a power of two, but not necessarily so. The reason the result is always nonzero is because the operation can *always* be carried without touching the highest bit, and at least that bit will show up in the output.

Comment: Ismael Luceno's comment is a better explanation for this observation

Comment: as noted in comments above, the statement in point 2: "which returns the highest power of 2 not greater than num", is incorrect. It should more accurately read "which returns *at least* the highest power of 2 not greater than num". I have made an edit to this answer and it is waiting for peer review.

Answer (score 8):

Well,

if you have X = 1000 then x-1 = 0111. And 1000 && 0111 is 0000.

Each number X that is a power of 2 has an x-1 that has ones on the position x has zeroes. And a bitwise and of 0 and 1 is always 0.

If the number x is not a power of two, for example 0110. The x-1 is 0101 and the and gives 0100.

For all combinbations within 0000 - 1111 this leads to

```
   X  X-1 X && X-1  
0000 1111 0000   
0001 0000 0000 
0010 0001 0000
0011 0010 0010
0100 0011 0000
0101 0100 0100
0110 0101 0100
0111 0110 0110
1000 0111 0000
1001 1000 1000
1010 1001 1000
1011 1010 1010
1100 1011 1000
1101 1100 1100
1110 1101 1100
1111 1110 1110
```

And there is no need for a separate check for 1.

Comment: But of course there is a need to check for 0, since 0 is not a power of 2, but tests as if it is.

Comment: A few things here - first, I think you're using `&&` a few places where you meant `&`. `n && (n-1)` would be 1 almost everywhere (except for n=0 and n=1, right?) Second, 1 is a power of 2, but the "need" depends on context we never saw ('true iff the power is positive/natural', or conversely, 'true iff exactly one bit is set', etc.) Nothing personal, this was almost a decade ago anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer this approach that relies on two's complement:

```
bool checkPowTwo(int x){
    return (x & -x) == x;
}
```

Comment: This function has the same shortcoming as returning `(x & (x - 1)) == 0`: it returns `1` for `x = 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Explained [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/ten-ways-to-check-if-an-integer-is-a-power-of-two-in-c/) nicely

Also the expression given considers 0 to be a power of 2. To fix that use
`!(x & (x - 1)) && x;` instead.

Comment: No that's wrong. There is no x such that 2**x = 0.
Hence x is not a power of 2.

Answer (score 2):

It determines whether integer is power of 2 or not.  If `(x & (x-1))` is zero then the number is power of 2.

For example,
    let `x` be 8 (`1000` in binary); then `x-1` = 7 (`0111`).

```
if    1000
  &   0111
---------------
      0000
```

C program to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a = 8;
    if ((a&(a-1))==0)
    {
        printf("the bit is power of 2  \n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("the bit is not power of 2\n");
    }
}
```

This outputs `the bit is power of 2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a = 7;
    if ((a&(a-1))==0)
    {
        printf("the bit is power of 2  \n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("the bit is not power of 2\n");
    }
}
```

This outputs `the bit is not power of 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose n is the given number,
**if n is power of 2** (n && !(n & (n-1)) will return 1 else return 0

Answer (score 1):

When you decrement a positive integer by 1:

1. if it is zero, you get `-1`.
2. if its least significant bit is `1`, this bit is set to `0`, the other bits are unchanged.
3. otherwise, all the low order `0` bits are set to `1` and the lowest `1` bit if set to `0`, the other bits are unchanged.

Case 1: `x & (x - 1)` is `0`, yet `x` is not a power of 2, trivial counter example.

Cases 2 and 3: if `x` and `x-1` have no bits in common, it means the *other bits* in both of the above cases are all zero, hence the number has a single 1 bit, hence it is a power of 2.

If `x` is negative, this test does not work for two's complement representation of signed integers as either decrementing overflows or `x` and `x-1` have at least the sign bit in common, which means `x & (x-1)` is not zero.

To test for a power of 2 the code should be:

```
int is_power_of_2(unsigned x) {
    return x && !(x & (x - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void powerof2(int a);
int a;

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
       printf("Enter any no. and Check  whether no is power of 2 or no \n");
       scanf("%d",&a);
       powerof2(a);
    }
}
void powerof2(int a)
{
    int count = 0;
    int b=0;
   while(a)
   {
     b=a%2;
     a=a/2;
     if(b == 1)
        {  count++;  }
   }
  if(count == 1)
   {
      printf("power of 2\n");
   }
  else
    printf("not power of 2\n");
}
```

Comment: In some case x & ( x-1) not working but we can do like this

Comment: Your `power2` function works only once! why make `count`, `a` and `b` global variables?

Comment: Hii Chqelie , 
yes only for once if inside main function use while(1) and will take printf() each time it will take value from user .
and int count and int b can take as globally also but initialized with zero
 while(1)
    {
      printf("Enter any value for 2 Power\n");
      scanf("%d",&a);
      powerof2(a);
    }

Comment: No, re-initializing `count` to `0` is a bad fix for this problem. Remove the global variables and define `b` and `count = 0` as local variables in `powerof2()`.

Comment: And indent your code properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes It should be local initialized, yes within the function are using

Answer (score -1):

Following program in C will find out if the number is power of 2 and also find which power of 2, the number is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int count=0
    unsigned int check=1;
    unsigned int position=0;
    unsigned int temp;
    //get value of a
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(int)*8;i++)//no of bits depend on size of integer on that machine
    {
        temp = a&(check << i);
        if(temp)
        {
            position = i;
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count == 1)
    {
        printf("%d is 2 to the power of %d",a,position);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not a power of 2");
    }
}
```

There are other ways to do this:-
if a number is a power of 2, only 1 bit will be set in the binary format

for example 8 is equivalent to 0x1000, substracting 1 from this, we get 0x0111.

End operation with the original number(0x1000) gives 0.

if that is the case, the number is a power of 2

```
    void IsPowerof2(int i)
    {
    if(!((i-1)&1))
    {
    printf("%d" is a power of 2, i);
    }
    }
```

another way can be like this:-

If we take complement of a number which is a power of 2,

for example complement of 8 i.e 0x1000 , we get 0x0111 and add 1 to it, we get

the same number, if that is the case, that number is a power of 2

```
    void IsPowerof2(int i)
    {
    if(((~1+1)&i) == 1)
    {
    printf("%d" is a power of 2,i):
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain *how* this answers the question.  "Here's some other ways to do the same thing" doesn't provide the enlightenment that was requested.