# Check if a number is 2^n

Tags: c, math, logic, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2)

This question has been asked in an interview.

How to check if a number is in `2^n` format {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ....}

without using  `*`, `/`, `+`, `-`, `%` operators?

And you can't use loops also.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053582/how-does-this-bitwise-operation-check-for-a-power-of-2)

Comment: No loops? What about 32 if-statements? :-)

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/600293/341970

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check if there is exactly one bit set in the binary representation.

Comment: aka "Is `N & (N-1)` zero" if one were actually aiming for efficiency and not random interview question requirements.

Comment: Amber: >without using *, /, +, -, % operators

Comment: @ both of you: I'm aware. I'm just pointing out the *efficient* way of doing it, hence why it's a *comment* and not an answer.

Comment: @Cicada the question is fairly nonsensical if it isn't.

Comment: @Cicada unless we're assuming integers, *any* number greater than or equal to zero is a power of 2.

Comment: There's an x86 assembly instruction that counts the number of set bits in an integer value.

Comment: @Amber What I meant is, the number could be a floating point.

Comment: @Cicada I think what Amber means is that, e.g. 1.3 is two to the 0.37851162325373. If you're willing to work with non-integrals in general then everything positive is a power of two.

Comment: While Amber's comment is correct for the real numbers, it's not correct for any type representable on a computer. For example, for floating point types, you could try the base-2 log rounded either up or down, but when you go back to exponentiate it, you'll raise an inexact exception even if the right result value does come out. Thus conceptually it's not a "power of two" even in the weirdness of the floating point number system.

Answer (score 9):

Use the good old `n & (n - 1) == 0`, transformed in a way that does not use operator `-`.

```
int powerOfTwo(int number)
{
    int numberMinusOne = --number;
    ++number;

    if (number == 0)
        return 0;

    return (number & numberMinusOne) == 0;
}
```

Comment: is there a performance gain by avoiding `-`?

Comment: @Chethan I don't think so. It was just a restriction stated by the OP.