# How does "&" work for numeric comparison?

Tags: ruby

```
def power_of_two?(n)
  n & (n-1) == 0
end
```

This method checks if a given number `n` is a power of two.
How does this work? I don't understand the usage of `&`

Comment: I think this function may incorrectly answer that 0 is a power of 2

Comment: Do you not understand what the "&" does, or do you not understand why this should return whether n is a power of 2?

Comment: It is the case that this function does return True if n is a power of two.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I hadn't ruby installed. now I can say it does return that 0 is a power of 2.  0 & -1
=> 0

Comment: Likely this is because of the twos-compliment representation of -1 as all ones, whereas 0 is all zeros. So we know: The function returns True if n is a power of two. And we know: The function returns true if n is not a power of two (since zero is not a (finite) power of two).

Comment: So, this is a special case. In general the function "power_of_two?" returns True if and only if n is a power of two or n is zero.

Comment: @hft I didn´t understand what & does

Comment: 40 minutes in and still no proofs! So far all of the answers just talk in generalities about bit-twiddling. We need an answer that proves: 1) if `n` is a power of `2`, then `n&(n-1)==0` and 2) if `n&(n-1)==0` then `n` is a power of `2`. Now that should not be so difficult. And forget the examples!

Comment: @CarySwoveland - what proof are you missing?

Comment: if using this method with 2's complement integers, it'll also answer that the minimum negative integer is a power of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is called Bitwise AND operator.

[The `AND` operator](http://calleerlandsson.com/2014/02/06/rubys-bitwise-operators/) walks through the binary representation of two supplied integers bit by bit. If the bits at the same position in both integers are 1 the resulting integer will have that bit set to 1. If not, the bit will be set to 0:

```
(a = 18).to_s(2)     #=> "10010"
(b = 20).to_s(2)     #=> "10100"
(a & b).to_s(2)      #=> "10000"
```

if the number is a power of two already, then one less will result in a binary number that only has the lower-order bits set.  Using `&` there will do nothing.

- Example with 8: `0100 & (0100 - 1)` --> `(0100 & 0011)` --> `0000`

To understand it follow "[How does this bitwise operation check for a power of 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053582/how-does-this-bitwise-operation-check-for-a-power-of-2/1053606#1053606)".

Example through IRB:

```
>> 4.to_s(2)
=> "100"
>> 3.to_s(2)
=> "11"
>> 4 & 3
=> 0
>>
```

This is why you can say `4` is *power of 2* number.

Answer (score 1):

The "&" is a bit-wise "AND" (see http://calleerlandsson.com/2014/02/06/rubys-bitwise-operators/) operator. It compares two numbers, as explained in the following example:

Suppose that n=4 (which is a power of two). This means that n-1=3. In binary (which I'm writing with ones and zeros in quotes like "1101011101" so we can see the bits) we have n="100" and n-1="011".

The bit-wise AND of these two numbers is 0="000" (in the following, each column only contains a single 1, never two 1s)

```
100          <-- this is n, n=4
011          <-- this is n-1, n-1=3
---
000          <-- this is n & (n-1)
```

As another example, now lets say that n=14 (not a power of two) and so n-1=13. In that case n="1110" and n-1="1101", and we have n & (n-1) = 12

```
1110         <-- this is n, n=14
1101         <-- this is n-1, n-1=13
----
1100         <-- this is n & (n-1)
```

In the above example, the first two columns of n and n-1 both contain a 1, thus the AND of those columns is one.

Okay, lets consider one final example where n is again a power of two (this should make it abundently clear if it is not already why "poweroftwo?" is written as it is. Suppose n=16 (which is a power of two).

Suppose that n=16 (which is a power of two). This means that n-1=15 so we have n="10000" and n-1="01111".

The bit-wise AND of these two numbers is 0="00000" (in the following, each column only contains a single 1, never two 1s)

```
10000          <-- this is n, n=16
01111          <-- this is n-1, n-1=15
---
00000          <-- this is n & (n-1)
```

Caveat: In the special case that n=0, the function "power_of_two?" will return True even though n=0 is not a power of two. This is because 0 is represented as a bit string of all zeros, and anything ANDed with zero is zero.

So, in general, the function "power_of_two?" will return True if and only if n is a power of two or n is zero. The above examples only illustrate this fact, they do not prove it... However, it is the case.

Comment: check the `tag` under the question. It's `ruby`

Comment: ah, okay, it wasn't commented originally

Answer (score 1):

The procedure for decreasing one from a binary number is, starting from the least significant bit:

1. if the bit is `0` - turn it into `1` and continue to the next significant bit
2. if the bit is `1` - turn it into `0` and stop.

This means that if there is more than one `1` digit in a number *not all digits will be toggled* (since you stopped before you got the most significant bit).

Let us say the **first** `1` in our number `n` is at position `i`. If we shift right the number `n` we'll get the part of the number which did not change when we decreased one, let's call that `m`. If we shift the number `n-1` we should get *the same number `m`*, exactly because it is the part that did not change when we decreased one:

```
n >> i == m
(n - 1) >> i == m
```

Shifting right two numbers by the same amount will also shift right by the same amount the result of `&`ing them:

```
(n >> i) & ((n - 1) >> i) == 0 >> i
```

But `0 >> i` is `0`, no matter the `i`, so:

```
(n >> i) & ((n - 1) >> i) == 0
```

Let's put `m` where we know it is:

```
m & m == 0
```

But we also know that:

```
m & m == m # for any m
```

So `m == 0`!

Therefore `n & (n - 1) == 0` if and only if there is at most one `1` bit in the number `n`.

The only numbers which have at most one `1` bit are all the (non-negative) powers of `2` (a leading `1` and a non-negative number of zeroes after it), and the number `0`.

QED

Comment: This looks promising, but it is not clear why "`n & (n-1) == 0` iff there is only one `1`-bit in the number `n`" follows from "not all digits will toggled".

Comment: @CarySwoveland - added the proof for why not all digits toggled leads to a single `1` digit

Comment: Nice one, @Uri. It's not surprising that our proofs contain similarities, but yours is more direct. I think it can be simplified, however. If you start with the assumption `n&(n-1)==0`, then you've shown that when you add `1` to `n-1` to get `m`, at position `i`, `n` has a `1` and `m` has a zero, meaning that `n != n` (since `m=n`), the needed contradiction. Hence, `n&(n-1)` != 0 when `n` is not a power of `2`. It's also true that `n` and `m` both have zeros in positions < i and have the same bits in postions > `i`, but I don't think that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to prove that

```
n & (n-1) == 0
```

if and only if `n` is a power of `2`.

We may assume that `n` is an integer greater than `1`. (In fact, I will use this assumption to obtain a contraction.)

If `n` is a power of `2`, its binary representation has `1` at bit-offset

```
p = log2(n)
```

and `0`s at all lower-order bit positions `j`, `j < p`.  Moreover, since `(n-1)+1 = n`, `n-1` must have `1`'s at all bit offsets `j`, `0 <= j < p`.  Therefore,

```
n & (n-1) == 0
```

It remains to prove that if `n` is not a power of `2` and

```
n & m == 0
```

then `m != n-1`. I assume that `m = n-1` and will obtain a contraction, thereby completing the proof.

`n`'s most significant bit is of course 1. Since `n` is not a power of 2, `n` has at least one other bit equal to `1`. Among those 1-bits, consider the one at the most significant bit position `j`.

Since `n & (n-1) == 0`, `n-1` must have a `0` at position `j` of its binary representation. When we add `1` to `n-1`, to make it equal `n`, it must have a `1` at offset `j`, meaning that `n-1` must have `1`'s in all bit positions < `j`. Moreover, `(n-1)+1` has zeroes in all bit positions < `j` after `1` is added. But since `n = (n-1)+1`, that can only be true if `j == 0`, since `n & (n-1) == 0`. Hence, for this to be true, `n`'s most-significant and least-significant bits most both equal `1` and all other bits must equal zero. However, since `n = (n-1)+1`, that would imply `n-1==0` and hence that `n == 1`, the needed contradiction.

(Whew! There's got to be an easier proof!)

Comment: Again Nice Algorithmic approach. I need to learn from you this part computer science.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a power of two, it takes the binary form of a single bit of value 1 followed by zeros. Any such value when decremented will take the form of a run of 1's, thus when using the bitwise-and, since it's necessarily less than the former, it will mask it out. E.g.

0b1000 & (0b1000 - 1) = 0b1000 & 0b111 = 0

So, anything (num - 1) might become, the key here is touching the highest bit of num, by decreasing it, we clear it out.

On the other hand, if a number is not a power of two, the result must be non-zero.

The reason behind is that the operation can always be carried without touching the highest bit, because there will always be a non-zero bit in the way, and so at least the highest bit makes it's way to the mask and will show up in the result.