# What is the best way to determine if a given number is a power of two?

Tags: javascript

Is there a more effective way to return `true` if `n` is a power of two or `false` if not?

```
function isPowerOfTwo(n) {
  return Math.pow(2, Math.round(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)));
}
```

Comment: So far, I have been able to convert a number to a valid power of two number here: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/b0uggk34/1/

Comment: just do this: `return x == n;` http://jsfiddle.net/6txdrrdv/

Comment: Thanks, sometimes my thoughts are clouded and I can't think logically

Comment: `return (Math.log(n)/Math.log(2)) % 1 === 0`

Comment: ok I will give you the upvote ;) Give me a tip too?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can actually use ECMAScript5 `Math.log`:

```
function powerOfTwo(x) {
    return (Math.log(x)/Math.log(2)) % 1 === 0;
}
```

Remember, in math, to get a logarithm with an arbitrary base, you can just divide log<sub>10</sub> of the operand (`x` in this case) by log<sub>10</sub> of the base. And then to see if the number is a regular integer (and not a floating point), just check if the remainder is 0 by using the modulus `%` operator.

In ECMAScript6 you can do something like this:

```
function powerOfTwo(x) {
    return Math.log2(x) % 1 === 0;
}
```

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2) for `Math.log2`.

Comment: Math.log(1000)/Math.log(10) % 1 == 0 
will give false, however it should give true, due to rounding off error in decimal points so this is not the best way.

Comment: const isPowerOfTwo2 = (x) => (Math.log(x) / Math.log(2)) % 1 === 0;
isPowerOfTwo2(2147483648);
false

yet 2147483648 = 2^31

Answer (score 30):

Source: [Bit twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2),

```
function powerOf2(v) {
    return v && !(v & (v - 1));
}
```

You just bitwise AND the previous number with the current number. If the result is falsy, then it is a power of 2.

The explanation is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1053594/1903116).

Note:

- This will not be 100% true for programming, mathematical, [also read 'interviewing'].  Some edge cases not handled by this are decimals (0.1, 0.2, 0.8…) or zero values (0, 0.0, …)

Answer (score 3):

Using bitwise operators, this is by far the best way in terms of efficiency and cleanliness of your code:

```
function PowerofTwo(n){
    return ((x != 0) && !(x & (x - 1)));
}
```

what it does is checks the bits that make up the number, i.e. 8 looks like this:

```
1 0 0 0
```

`x-1` or 7 in this case looks like this

```
0 1 1 1
```

when the bitwise operator `&` is used it invokes an && on each bit of the number (thus `1 & 1 = 1`, `1 & 0 = 0`, `0 & 1 = 0`, `0 & 0 = 1`):

```
 1 0 0 0
-0 1 1 1
=========
 0 0 0 0
```

since the number turns into an exact 0 (or false when evaluted as a boolean) using the `!` flag will return the correct answer

if you were to do this with a number like 7 it would look like this:

```
 0 1 1 1
-0 1 1 0
=========
 1 1 1 0
```

returning a number greater than zero causing the `!` flag to take over and give the correct answer.

Comment: `(x != 0)` is the same as `x` . Thus, your answer is the same as @thefourtheye 's

Comment: @blex: Wrong. `x != 0` converts `x` to a number, just using `x` would convert it to a boolean. Big difference! Still, the answer is unnecessary.

Comment: @FelixKling Of course, I meant that in this case, it made no difference, since `0` and `false` are false**y** values, and any other integer and `true` are truthy.

Comment: with ES6 `isPowerOfTwo = n => !(n&n-1)`

Comment: Great explanation doesn't cover the negative tho.

`return (x>0) && ((x != 0) && !(x & (x - 1)));`

Answer (score 3):

A number is a power of 2 if and only if log base 2 of that number is whole. The function below computes whether or not that is true:

```
function powerOfTwo(n){
    // Compute log base 2 of n using a quotient of natural logs
    var log_n = Math.log(n)/Math.log(2);
    // Round off any decimal component
    var log_n_floor = Math.floor(log_n);
    // The function returns true if and only if log_n is a whole number
    return log_n - log_n_floor == 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function PowerOfTwo(n){
  // Exercise for reader: confirm that n is an integer
  return (n !== 0) && (n & (n - 1)) === 0;
}
console.log(PowerOfTwo(3))
console.log(PowerOfTwo(4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Making use of ES6's [Math.clz32(n)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32) to count leading zeros of a 32-bit integer from 1 to 2³² - 1:

```
function isPowerOf2(n) {
  return Math.clz32(n) < Math.clz32(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
/**
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {boolean}
 */
const isPowerOfTwo = function(n) {
    if(n == 0) return false;

    while(n % 2 == 0){
        n = n/2
    }
    return n === 1
};
```