# Return an array containing all indices that are powers of 2

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on this problem.  Math is not one of strong suites.  Any tips would be great.  It is supposed to return an array of indices that are powers of 2.

```js
function secondPower(arr) {
    // Return an array containing all indices that are powers of 2
    newArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] % (2 ** i) === 0  && arr[i] != 1){
            newArray.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

An example of the solution is

```
secondPower([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

returns

```
[2,3,5]
```

Comment: Do you mean **indices** that are a power of two, or values in the array that are powers of two? Note also that 1 is a power of 2, while 6 is not, and 8 is.

Comment: Also the `Math.log2()` function would simplify things, or you could compile an array of the first 30 or 40 powers of 2 quite quickly.

Comment: This is a funky question that I got.  I've looked at ```Math.log2()``` and that didn't produce the results that the test wanted.  It's not like any of the math rules I've looked up.

Comment: If `log2()` returns an integer, you've got a power of 2

Comment: Why would it return [2,3,5] ? Arrays are zero indexed, so by your criteria, the index 2 points to `3`, and index 5 points to `6`, and neither `3` nor `6` are powers of 2. Please be specific about your question and edit it to add appropriate context, don't add comments.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't make sense with the answer that the problem wants to come up with.  @AndyRay this is all it has provided.  There is no further context.  This is as specific as I can be.

Comment: 0 isnot power of 2; 1 is power of 2: 2^0. Since arr[1] is "2", it comes on the result.

Comment: @BrianMoore don't copy and paste questions verbatim without making an attempt to understand them. You didn't even ask a question here. Did you write this code? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to be specific about what you've tried and what you don't understand. A question with many comments means it needs work. We don't know what it "it" is when you say "the answer that it wants".

Comment: @AndyRay `[2,3,5]` are the values at the indexes that are powers of 2.

Comment: @Unmitigated what? 3 and 5 aren't powers of 2. Nor is the element at the 5th index, which is `6`.

Comment: @AndyRay Those are the values at the indexes 1 (`2**0`), 2 (`2**1`), and 4 (`2**2`) in the array.

Comment: Ah, I see. This question is a nightmare

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use bitwise operators, that are LOTS FASTER. But they only works for power of 2:

```
function secondPower(arr) {
    var result = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (isPower(k)) { result.push(arr[k]); }
    }
    return result;
}

//... this function checks if there is only one 1 on the binary number
function isPower(k) {
    var found = false;
    while (k > 0) {
        if (k & 1 == 1) {
            if (found) { return false; }
            found = true;
        }
        k >>= 1;
    }
    return found;
}

secondPower([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start at index 1 and keep multiplying by 2 until the value reaches the length of the array. This solution runs in logarithmic time and avoids a linear loop over all of the indexes.

```js
function secondPower(arr) {
    const res = [];
    for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i <<= 1) res.push(arr[i]);
    return res;
}
console.log(secondPower([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
```

Comment: this should be the selected solution. It may just lack a bit of explanation on how bit shifting is related to powers of 2 (and actually the fastest way to compute them)

Answer (score 2):

At first, I had a hard time understanding what this was asking, but this returned the indices and worked for me.

```
function secondPower(arr) {
// Return an array containing all indices that are powers of 2
// Double the value of i each time through the loop starting at 1
let newArr = [];
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i *= 2) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(secondPower([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [What is the best way to determine if a given number is a power of two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924280/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-given-number-is-a-power-of-two)

```js
const isPowerOf2 = v => v && !(v & (v - 1));
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].filter(isPowerOf2);
```

yields

```
[1, 2, 4, 8]
```

Comment: The question is looking for indexes that are powers of two.

Comment: No, the question is ambiguous, and should be closed

Comment: If you're going to answer, you should try to make an answer that responds to the question.

Comment: Please read the question and the comments before adding additional comments. This is most likely what is being asked, I'm just looking for fake internet points, and thought it was weird the accepted answer used a while loop

Comment: No, given that the accepted answer checks the indexes, your answer does not correspond to what is most likely being asked. The question title also clearly mentions "indices". See also the sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// if a number is a power of 2 its base 2 logarithm is an integer
const result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].reduce((a, v, i) => Number.isInteger(Math.log2(v)) ? a.concat(i) : a, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function secondPower(arr) {

// return an array containing all indices that are powers of 2
// your code here 

let array = [];
  
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    
  if(arr[2**i]) {
     array.push(arr[2**i]);
  }
    
 }
    
 return array;

}
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! Can you add more details to your answer such as explaination ? You can read [answer] for more informations

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up coming up with, using Math.pow(x, y) for the loopEnd expression - where x is to the power of y.

```
function secondPower(arr) {
  let powersOf2 = [];
  let num = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i = Math.pow(2, num += 1)) {
    powersOf2.push(arr[i]);
  } return powersOf2;
}

console.log(secondPower([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 
120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180]));
```

Yields:
[ 20, 30, 50, 90, 170 ]

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The `Math.log2()` static method returns the base 2 logarithm of a number.

Take the base-2 logarithm number of the indices to determine if the indices are power of 2

check if the result of the logarithm is an integer (no decimal part). if the result is an integer, then the index is a power of 2. Therefore, if the result is evaluated as a decimal then it will be false

Note: because array starts at index 0, if we do `Math.log2` it will result in '-infinity' therefore we can start at index = 1.

```
// example: 
// if i = 1, then 'Math.log2(1)' is 0 because 2^0 = 1, in this case Number.isInteger(0) returns true
// if i = 2, them 'Math.log2(2)' is 1 becuase 2^1 = 2, in this case Number.isInteger(1) returns true;
// if i = 3, then 'Math.log2(3)' is approximately 1.58496250072115 and Number.isInteger returns false indicating that the index of 3 is not a power of 2

function secondPower(arr) {
  let output = []; 
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Number.isInteger(Math.log2(i))) {
      output.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return output; 
}
```