# What does the bitwise code "$n & ($n - 1)" do?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

What does this code mean and what are other ways accomplish the same without using bit shifting?

```
if ($n & ($n - 1))
```

Comment: That's actually a bitwise-and, not a bit shift.

Comment: Why would you need to avoid bitwise operations this?

Comment: Because I don't understand them very well and a similar case might help me understand it better. And this is not homework. =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That formula [checks to see whether a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2) (if your condition as written is true, then the number is *not* a power of two).

Stated another way, your test checks to see whether there is more than one "1" bit set in the binary representation of `$n`. If there is zero or only one bit set, then your test will be false.

It is by far the most efficient way to determine that property.

Comment: Greg, the question is, essentially, an adaptation that tests to see if a number isn't a power of two. Without `== 0` PHP takes any non-zero value as true.

Comment: Yes, I thought the logical negation would be clear. Nevertheless, I have amended my answer to make that explicit.

Comment: Well, it isn't negation at first glance (that would be `!= 0`), and my impression of eyze is that he's on a beginner's level.

Comment: that's clever, i haven't seen this trick before.  i had to do some math in my head to validate that this would work. :)

Comment: It's one of those "Old C Hacker's Tricks", except it should be `$n ^ ($n-1)`, and it's used to find the smallest '1' bit of n.

As it is written, it'll group 0 with all of your powers of two. Of course, my version will show '0' as being full of ones - but then, having more than one '1' could be seen as a useful way to show that there wasn't any '1' in the original number.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Just to make thing a little clearer, the '^' sign in the formula above is supposed to be the eXclusive-OR (XOR) sign, which if you don't know it, is like a one-bit version of "!="

Answer (score 5):

First, this code is valid PHP, so your title is poor.

Second, the binary arithmetic going on looks something like this:

```
42 = 101010
   &
41 = 101001
-----------
40 = 101000
```

Like Greg states this is the fastest way to check for a power of 2 number, but the code you've given checks to see if the number is *not a power of 2*. This can easily be ascertained by PHP's policy of: any non-null/non-zero value is true.

Answer (score 0):

When we use ($n & ($n - 1)) then it converts $n & ($n-1) to its binary values and does binary AND operation.
*Example*

```
  3 = 0011
  4 = 0100
  5 = 0101

  3 = 0011
       &
  4 = 0100
------------
       0

  4 = 0100
       &
  5 = 0101
-----------
       100
```

To check if given number is power of 2 or not we alway use formulae
($n & ($n - 1) == 0) which means ANDing of $n & $n-1 is equals to 0 or not.

> [Online AND Operation Calculator](http://easyonlineconverter.com/converters/bitwise-calculator.html)