# what is the means of i &=(i-1) in java

Tags: java, loops, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
    int n;
    for ( n = 0; i >0; n++)
    {
        i &= (i-1);
    }
    return n;
```

//maybe its function is to count the number of 1, I don't know the sentence means

Comment: duplicate question Refer Original here:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1551500/3323444

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Does The Bitwise & (AND) Work In Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256644/how-does-the-bitwise-and-work-in-java)

Comment: @krishnakant No, this is different, it's a loop, it's not just checking to see if it's a power of 2

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed counting the number of one-bits in the value of i. It does however only work properly for positive values. The JRE provided Integer.bitCount(i) does the same and it works in constant time as well as for negative values.

As for how it works, its hard to understand if you're not familar with binary arithmetic. What basically happens that in each loop the least significant set bit cancels out and the loop stops when all bits have been canceled out.

It does not work properly with negative values because the loops condition has been chosen poorly. It should be i != 0 instead of i > 0, then it works with negative values as well.

Answer (score 2):

[& is the bitwise AND operation in Java.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm) What this function is doing is counting the number of those operations it take to reach 0.

This function is counting the number of "1's" in a binary representation of a number (a bit of research allowed me to find [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/)). The way this works is it flips the rightmost bit that is 1 on every pass in the loop until the number is zero.

For instance, if we run this function on 100:

```
1100100 & 1100011 = 1100000 //Flipped the rightmost one bit (100 & 99)
1100000 & 1011111 = 1000000 //Then the next (96 & 95)
1000000 & 0111111 = 0000000 //And finally the last (64 & 63)
```

So the loop will have executed 3 times, indicating 3 "on" bits in the number 100.

Comment: But it answers the question as written down. So maybe the answer is incomplete, but so far, it isn't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It means erase last bit of 1's.
For example, we count # of 1's for `8`. 
Loop1: 8 & 7.

```
8 = 0b1000
7 = 0b0111
```

We got `8 & 7 = 0`.
Since we only have one 1's. The result will be 1.

If we count # of 1's for `7`.
Loop1: 7 & 6

```
7 = 0b111
6 = 0b110
```

We got `7 & 6 = 6`. As you can see, `6 = 0b110`, we erase last bit of 1. Then, we count 
Loop2: 6 & 5

```
6 = 0b110
5 = 0b101
```

We got `6 & 5 = 4`. As you can see, `4 = 0b100`, we erase last bit of 1. Then, we count
Loop3: 4 & 3

```
4 = 0b100
3 = 0b011
```

We got `4 & 3 = 0`.
Since we have three loops, the # of 1's for `7` is 3.