# Is there any way to use one while loop in this code instead of 2?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

i'm kinda new to this and have just learnt loops. so i wanted to enter 187654321, 998765432 in but i think this thing i wrote is so inefficient that it just timed out :/ it works for smaller numbers tho! would appreciate any help/tips hehe :')

```
import java.util.*;

class PowerOf3 {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter start and end: ");
    int start = sc.nextInt();
    int end = sc.nextInt();
    
    int ans = countNumbers(start, end);
    
    
    System.out.println("Answer = "+ans);
  }
  
  // Count the number of integers from start to
  // end (both inclusive) that are power of 3
  public static int countNumbers(int start, int end) {
    int count = 0;
    if (start == 1) {
      count = -1;
    } else {
    count =0;
    }
    while (end>=start) {
      double n = end;
      while (n>1) {
        n = (double) n/3;
      }
      if (n==1) {
        count++;
      }
      end--;
    }
    return count;  // stub, to be replaced by your code
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example with small numbers? That will help others to understand what your code will do? A better solution may be provided.

Comment: If inner-while loop corresponds to a Math Function in the library, you can try using that.

Comment: There are only 20 powers of 3 between 1 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You could store these in a list and just count the number between start and end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804311/how-to-check-if-an-integer-is-a-power-of-3

Comment: hmm, Math.pow? i tried using that just now but i wasnt about it and it became an utter mess :(

Comment: Check stackoverflow page I posted in the comments. There is one line solution without looping

Comment: unsigned :   bool isPower3(std::uint32_t value) {
    return value != 0 && 3486784401u % value == 0;
}

Comment: signed :  bool isPower3(std::int32_t value) {
    return value > 0 && 1162261467 % value == 0;
}

Comment: @AntiqTech but that requires you to check _every_ number, one by one. There's no point in doing that: start at a known power of 3, you know the next power of 3 is just previous * 3.

Comment: @AntiqTech oo yes, i just saw it! i'm gonna try it out now! thankyouu

Comment: @AndyTurner  I understand your point but OP is already iterating an inner-while for every number. that's worse.

Comment: oh i had no idea there was a max value :/ i'll def try that out! thankss @AndyTurner

Comment: @AntiqTech you don't have to answer in an "only just better" way, though.

Comment: I wasn't posting a full answer anyway, I just gave OP a source to try out :D

Comment: I think you should use long values. The values you want to enter are too big and so, it might not be able to fit into `int` type of variables. Make it as a change and then try out..

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following code

```
double n = end;
      while (n>1) {
        n = (double) n/3;
      }
      if (n==1) {
        count++;
      }
```

With this one and try to run,

```
int n = end;
      while (n%3 == 0) {
        n /= 3;
      }
      if (n==1) {
        count++;
      }
```

mod and integer operations can save time.

Comment: This modification reduces your running time from 103407 milli seconds to just 2559 milli seconds with the input (start = 187654321 & end = 998765432) @chickennugget.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with a HashSet that stores all the powers_of_3 (from `3^0` to `3^19`, considering integer). That code produces almost the similar timing as **@abhimanyue**.

Then I modify **@abhimanyue**'s code keeping in mind with what the program actually doing, here is my code.

```
class PowerOf3_final 
{
    //public static Set<Integer> powerOf3 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //System.out.print("Enter start and end: ");
        
        int start = 19683;      //int start = sc.nextInt(); 
        int end = 1162261467;   //int end = sc.nextInt();
        
        long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        /*
        int pow3=1;
        for(int i =0; i<20; i++) {
            powerOf3.add(pow3);
            pow3 *= 3;
        }
        */
        
        System.out.println("Answer = "+countNumbers(start, end));
        
        long en = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        System.out.println("Execution time = "+(en-st)+" milli seconds.");
    }
      
    // Count the number of integers from start to
    // end (both inclusive) that are power of 3
    public static int countNumbers(int start, int end) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        
        if (start == 1) {
          count = -1;
        } 
        
        while (end>=start) 
        {
            /*
            double n = end;         
            while (n>1) {
                n = (double) n/3;
            }
            if (n==1) {
                count++;
            }
            */
            
            int n = end;
            while (n%3 == 0) {
              n /= 3;
            }
            if (n==1) {
              count++;
              end /=3;  // no need to check other values,
            }
            
            /*
            if(powerOf3.contains(end)) {
                count++;
            }
            */
            
            else end--;
        }
        return count;  // stub, to be replaced by your code
    }
}
```

This code runs **superfast** for all the inputs (within integer range).
Still there are scope to improve the timing of this code.

Comment: "Still there are scope to improve the timing of this code." Indeed: try with end = 1162261466.

Comment: hello! i dont really know about timing but gosh this was the easiest to understand, for a beginner like me! (i didnt even understand the method my prof tried to explain HAHA) i really really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The key to doing this quickly is not to check all numbers, which you are doing with the `while (end>=start) { /* ... */ end--; }`.

There are about 2 billion numbers between 1 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (the extreme case of the inputs), only 20 of which are powers of 3.

And, if you can find a power of 3, you can find the next largest one straight away by multiplying it by 3. Of course, the easiest place to start is 1.

Since there are only 20 possible values in your range, just iterate over all 20 (or until you exceed `end`), count the number which happen to fall within the input range. This will be so fast that it's not worth worrying about trying to start at a larger power of 3 that's within the range.

Just start at 3<sup>0</sup>, keep doing to 3<sup>19</sup>.

```
int limit = 1 + (int) Math.floor(Math.log(Integer.MAX_VALUE) / Math.log(3));  // 20.

return (int)
    IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i * 3)    // A stream containing only powers of 3
        .limit(limit)                   // Stop before you overflow
        .takeWhile(i -> i <= end)
        .filter(i -> i >= start)        // Take the ones in the range.
        .count();
```

Or, with a basic loop:

```
int count = 0;
int p = 1;
while (p <= end) {
  if (p >= start) ++count;

  if (p > Integer.MAX_VALUE / 3) break;

  p *= 3;
}
return count;
```

This approach [takes <1μs](https://ideone.com/3Kzczv) to solve the worst-case problem (1 to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) (once warmed up); and seems to only be around 10x slower without warmup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is not efficiency. your code suffer from infinite loop

You use (int variable) type which has maximum value of 2147483647

when you exceed this number inside (increment ++) the loop, the loop will not end rather the number will circle like the following 1 2 3 4 then -4 - 3 -2 -1  or in you example:
2147483646,  2147483647, then 2147483647-,  2147483646-,  etc..