# Setting column constraint on a table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have a column that should contain one of values of 2 power n: 2,4,8,16,32 etc. I want to enforce that on table schema level - is there a way to specify such a column constraint?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a reason just why you are doing this ?

Comment: Ok, it just occurred to me that I should rather store n than 2 power n :) Case solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PowerOfTwo]
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_PowerOfTwo] 
CHECK  ((log([Value])/log(2)=round(log([Value])/log(2), 0, 1)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Shamelessly stealing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2) you could use bitwise operations to do this pretty efficiently.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT
    ckname CHECK (colName > 0 AND (colName & (colName - 1) =0))
```

Answer (score 2):

how about defining the column to be N.  then all uses of that column would be 2^n by definition instead of constraint.

otherwise - you could put trigger logic in place to validate each value as it is entered or updated.

Comment: I already figured that out a couple of minutes ago :) I'll upvote you anyway as it's a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Assume your column name is N.  Try something like

```
CHECK(LOG(N)/LOG(2) = TRUNC(LOG(N)/LOG(2)))
```

The intent is to verify that the binary logarithm of the value N is an integer, which would mean that N was a power of 2.  Not sure if SQL Server supports the LOG and TRUNC functions - substitute in the correct names as needed.

Edit: as I re-read this I realized that rounding might cause a problem (I forgot the Second Commandment of Floating Point, which is: Thou Shalt Never Compare Floating Point Values For Equality!).  OK, how about

```
CHECK(ABS(LOG(N)/LOG(2) - TRUNC(LOG(N)/LOG(2))) < 0.00001)
```

or substitute whatever error tolerance you'd like for the 0.00001.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column check:

```
CHECK (column_name IN (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ..., 2147483648))
```

Comment: Reasons for downvoting anyone?

Comment: Yes I am serious. How is this answer conceptually different from the accepted answer? Yes, I thought it'd be better to use a simple list of values, since there are few, rather than call `log` 4 times, but other than that (irrelevant) difference, there's nothing else. Or are you implying your column is actually of type `double`, not `int` ? In this case the accepted answer is wrong, too, because there's a finite floating-point precision because of which the comparison will likely be less true than you'd expect.