# fastest way to find a given number 'n' can be absolutely expressed as 2^m

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2)

fastest way to find a given number 'n' can be expressed as 2^m

ex: `16= 2^4`

naive solution: divide given number by 2 until the remainder becomes 0 (if successful) or less than two (if not successful)

Can someone tell me whats the other fastest way to compute this ?

Comment: +1 to counteract downvotes for no reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fastest way:

```
if (n != 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0)
```

If the number is a power of two, it will be represented in binary as 1 followed by m zeroes. After subtracting 1, it will be just m ones. For example, take m=4 (n=16)

```
10000 binary = 16 decimal
01111 binary = 15 decimal
```

Perform a bitwise "and" and you'll get 0. So it gives the right result in that case.

Now suppose that `n` is *not* exactly 2<sup>m</sup> for some m. Then subtracting one from it *won't affect the top bit*... so when you "and" together `n` and `n-1` the top bit will still be set, so the result won't be 0. So there are no false positives either.

EDIT: I originally didn't have the `n != 0` test... if n is zero, then `n & anything` will be zero, hence you get a false positive.

Comment: @Gumbo: I don't believe the question is about finding `m` - it's about determining whether there *is* such an integer `m`. I could be wrong though - it's not expressed very clearly.

Comment: @sdcwc: Good point. Will edit.

Comment: perfect answer. by the way its not a HW gumbo, 
thanks
ram

Comment: Isn't popcount faster? return (std::popcount(val)==1)?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: This is an *algorithmic* question. Yes, there may be hardware that makes the result blindingly fast on some platforms, and a standard library that exposes it on some platforms - but that's really not an algorithmic answer.