# floor(x) does not equal x where x is a double

Tags: c, double

I have a simple code to check if an INTEGER n is a power of 2

```
bool isPowerOfTwo(int n)
{
    double x = log(n)/log(2);
    return floor(x) == x ;
}
```

Most of the test cases are fine until n = 536870912 = 2^29.

In this case, the function return FALSE (which is not correct).
I used printf to print floor(x) and x, both of them give 29.000000. But still, it returns FALSE.
I hexdump x and floor(x)

x:

**01** 00 00 00 00 00 3D 40

floor(x):

**00** 00 00 00
00 00 3D 40

Why would floor(x) change a certain bit of x when x is a round number (29)? How to fix this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

FYI:

- gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
- Target: x86_64-linux-gnu

EDIT: interestingly, if log() is replaced with log10(), it works fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not for C...

Comment: @TedLyngmo C, so `std::popcount` unfortunately doesn't exist :\ though builtins exsit, and I think `(!(n & (n - 1))` should work too (Though I think it incorrectly returns true for 1 and 0).

Comment: Ah ... sorry, missed that - deleted comment.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 1 should be true, right (2^0)? I think your test works fine if a test for zero is added: `return !(n & (n - 1)) && n;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh yeah, forgot about power of 0 :p and yeah, that `&& n` should fix the 0 issue :)

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why did you decide to make `n` a signed integer? It should be obvious that `n<0` will cause problems. To be more specific a domain error occurs.

Comment: You know that there are simpler ways to check for power of 2? `x && !(x&(x-1))` should work for any unsigned integer `x`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638431/determine-if-an-int-is-a-power-of-2-or-not-in-a-single-line

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't know about this simpler solution you are discussing. Otherwise, this thread wouldn't have existed :). @12431234123412341234123 No reason at all for using n as signed integer, just a bit careless of me.

Comment: To start, use the standard C `log2` function instead of `log(n)/log(2)`. If your `log2` function is faithfully rounded (some implementations are not), this will return exact results for the power-of-two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would floor(x) change a certain bit of x when x is a round number (29)?

Because `double` you are using has no precision to store the result of calculations exact, so it rounds, and because the result of calculation is away from a whole number `floor` rounds to the whole number. On your platform `double` is [Double precision IEEE 745](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

| calculation | real result | rounded to double |
| --- | --- | --- |
| log(536870912) | 20.10126823623841397309 | 20.10126823623841474387 |
| log(2) | .69314718055994530941 | .69314718055994528623 |
| 20.10126823623841474387/.69314718055994528623 | 29.00000000000000208209 | 29.00000000000000355271 |
| (double)log(536870912)/(double)log(2) | 29.00000000000000000028 | 29.00000000000000355271 |

The result of calculation of `ln(536870912)/ln(2)` is `29.00000000000000355271` (i.e. `0x1.d000000000001p+4`). Floor then truncates the `1` and gives exact `29`.

Note how the result of `(double)log(536870912)/(double)log(2)` is closer to `29.00000000000000355271` then to `29`. You can play around with https://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html# and https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html to learn floats better.

> How to fix this problem ?

The usuall solutions: increase precision by using greater datatype (i.e. use `long double)` or use an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library. In this case, do not use floating point numbers at all, stick to integers.

Comment: Thanks. Very informative. I try long double but result does not change. Interestingly, log10() gives correct output.

Comment: @QuangDao: instead of `long double` which is not a perfect solution, use integer arithmetics since the argument is a integer anyway.

Comment: Re “The usuall solutions: increase precision by using greater datatype”: This is not a solution. Logarithms are irrational except for very limited cases, so most logarithms will not be representable in **any** floating-point base with **any** finite precision. Then there are three rounding errors in `log(a) / log(b)`, so sometimes the computer result will be less than the real-number result, even if the latter is an integer. Changing the precision changes which cases that happens in but does not eliminate them.

Comment: What would be a solution is using a faithfully rounded `log2`. Faithful rounding guarantees sufficient accuracy that when the real-number result is an integer (as it is for the base-two logarithm of powers of two, which is what OP needs here) that is in the interval where all integers are representable, the computed result is exact.

Answer (score 0):

Function which checks if is the power of 2 and if it is returns log2(x)

```
#define MAX(x)     (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(x))
#define HALF(x)    (1UL << (MAX(x) / 2))

int ispower2andLog(unsigned x)
{
    int result = 0;
    
    if(x > HALF(x))
    {
        for(int pos = MAX(x) / 2; pos < MAX(x); pos++)
        {
            if((1UL << pos) == x)
            {
                result = pos;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int pos = 0; pos <= MAX(x / 2); pos++)
        {
            if((1UL << pos) == x)
            {
                result = pos;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned testcases[] = {0, 2,4, 5, 0x100, HALF(UINT_MAX) - 1, HALF(UINT_MAX) - 0, HALF(UINT_MAX) + 1, UINT_MAX & (~(UINT_MAX >> 1)), UINT_MAX};

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(testcases) / sizeof(testcases[0]); i++)
        printf("%12u (%08x) result = %d\n", testcases[i], testcases[i], ispower2andLog(testcases[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following returns true iff `n` is a power of two:

```
_Bool isPowerOfTwo(int n)
{
    return 0 < n && n == (n & - (unsigned) n);
}
```

`- (unsigned) n` computes the two’s complement of `n` (because unsigned arithmetic wraps modulo a power of two). In the two’s complement of a positive number, all bits above the lowest 1 bit change. For example, `0100 0110` changes to `1011 1010`. So, when this is ANDed with the original number, the only bit on is the lowest 1 bit. If this equals the original number, the original number had only one bit set to 1, so it is a power of two. If it does not equal the original number, the original number had more than one bit set to 1, so it is not a power of two. (The case where the original number has no bits set to 1 is handled by the test `0 < n`.)

Answer (score -1):

Your method is not reliable for multiple reasons:

- converting an `int` might lose precision if the `int` type has more value bits than the floating point type. This would be the case when converting a `long long` to an IEEE-754 `double` type.
- both `log(n)` and `log(2)` are approximations: the result is rounded to the closest value representable as a `double`. Dividing these approximations might not produce the exact value of **log<sub>2</sub>(n)**, and the result is itself rounded so even a whole number might not be proof that `n` be an exact power of 2.
- if `n` is negative, `log(n)` might return a NAN and the test will evaluate to false, but `log` might trigger a signal and cause unexpected behavior. `log(0)` might return `-Infinity` or send a signal too.
- in a test like this, a floating point calculation is not the expected approach. Taking advantage of the binary representation of integers is a better solution.

A much simpler method is this:

```
bool isPowerOfTwo(unsigned int n) {
    return (n & (n - 1)) == 0 && n != 0;
}
```

Comment: `if n is negative, log(n) will return a NAN` This is not a requirement.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: yes, I was correcting the answer as you commented.

Comment: log(0) is also problematic

Comment: Well, I omitted checkings for clarity (even though my code is too simple already :) )