# Funneling in Java hashing

Tags: java

I read in [an article which says](http://www.cris.com/~ttwang/tech/hashsize.htm):

> It is a common practice to recommend a prime number to be the size of a hash table. This way, a funnel will occur only if the keys are multiples of the prime number.

Here, why should a prime number be used for the initial size, and what is funnelling?

Comment: @Tim Cooper Thanks for brilliantly editing and providing the links.Great work

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352378/java-hashmap-default-initial-capacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long answer: [here](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/evahash.html#funneling)

Short answer:

A **funnel** occurs when 2+ keys get hashed to the same value because of an error with the underlying hashing function. Like this:

```
Map<String,Object> myMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
Thing thing1, thing2;
thing1 = new Thing();
thing2 = new Thing();

myMap.put("ab", thing1);
myMap.put("ba", thing2);
```

If there is an inherent flaw in the hashing function used by `HashMap<K,V>`, a "funnel" could occur where the keys `ab` and `ba` both map to, say, `thing1`.

Think of a funnel as an actual funnel: multiple inputs get *funneled* into the same place.

**Edit**
If a hash function is flawed and does contain funnels, then a way to minimize their occurrence is to set the size of the table to being a prime number.

This is because, in terms of being a "class" (category) of numbers, prime numbers have the least amount of factors. According to that article, funnels occur when a given key is a factor or multiple of the size of the table. So if we set the table size to 100 (not a prime number), we introduce the *possibility* of funneling when the provided key is any *factor of 100*: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, ..., 100, 200, 300, etc.

But if we make the size of the table to a prime, say, 101... then the only *possibility* of a funnel occurs at: 1, 101, 202, 302, etc. We've greatly reduced the *possibility* of a funnel.

Comment: i liked the first part of your answer....but link is too complex to understand....can you explain it...

Comment: Please see my edit explaining primes. Also the article is (probably) graduate level, and I'm just mere JEE developer with a bachelors degree! My original explanation of what a funnel is and how it occurs should be enough to give you the general idea though. Good luck!

Comment: What is the difference between a funnel and a collision? Aren't collisions inevitable in hashing systems (but can be made improbable).

Answer (score 0):

I think to protect the keys to sit in proper place Hash table and you can look into funnelling http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/evahash.html#funneling