# String HashSet produces an output that doesn't match String Hash function

Tags: java, hashset

I am preparing for a UIL computer contest, and one of the practice questions asked involved a set, here it is, word for word:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("000");
set.add("212");
set.add("211");
set.add("555");
set.add("343");
System.out.println(set);
```

Now, I understand that HashSets are unsorted data structures, but there were 2 unsorted choices shown, and 1 sorted answer choice:

A) [000, 211, 343, 212, 555]

B) [000, 211, 212, 343, 555]

c) [000, 211, 555, 343, 212]

I naively picked B) the sorted answer, while the correct answer is A, but I still do not understand why. I found the hash code generated by each of the string's hash functions:

"000" - 47664

"212" - 49619

"211" - 49618

"555" - 52629

"343" - 50674

To my knowledge the hash set utilizes a hashtable as its backend. In that case, based on the hash codes, I don't understand why answer is incorrect. I plugged the code into java and it produces the result in the correct answer choice. What is going on here, how exactly does a HashSet add items to itself?

Comment: weird question. i thought different JVMs would give different results depending on implementation of hashset... so there must be something lower level they're wanting you to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Because the backing array can be smaller than hashcodes, the order is not determined by only `hashcode()`, but `hashcode() % arr.length;`. The default size of the backing array is `16`, so if you calculate the modulo for the hashcodes you listed, you'll get the correct order.

For elements with same hashcodes, the one inserted first is also the first to be printed. This is due to the buckets holding lists of all objects in the same bucket (and using `equals()` to determine whether they're the *same* object or if they just happened to get the same bucket).

Answer (score 1):

A [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) uses a `HashMap` as its backing data:

> This class implements the `Set` interface, backed by a hash table (actually a `HashMap` instance).

The `HashSet` uses the `HashMap` to quickly determine if an element is already present.

The [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap--) has a default capacity of `16`.

> Constructs an empty `HashMap` with the default initial capacity (16) and the default load factor (0.75).

You've added 5 items, not nearly enough to meet the load factor times capacity, so no resizing is done.

You need to know how the `HashMap` uses the hash code to determine which bucket to use.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632506/significance-of-power-of-2-in-java-util-hashmap-implementation), Java does `hash & (SIZE -1)` to extract only the lowermost *n* bits, where the capacity is 2<sup>n</sup>.

So, the bucket numbers are as follows:

"000" - 47664 -> 0

"212" - 49619 -> 3

"211" - 49618 -> 2

"555" - 52629 -> 5

"343" - 50674 -> 2

Printing out the set uses an `Iterator` that walks the buckets in order.  Within the same bucket, insertion order is used.

Therefore the order is:

1. "000" - 47664 -> 0
2. "211" - 49618 -> 2
3. "343" - 50674 -> 2
4. "212" - 49619 -> 3
5. "555" - 52629 -> 5

And that matches choice "A".

Answer (score 0):

"000" - 47664

"212" - 49619

"211" - 49618

"555" - 52629

"343" - 50674

Find the mod of each of them divided by 16. Then sort it. If there is a bucket match then last one added is first in the list ( since its "implemented as a stack" when there is a collision. )

Answer (score 0):

1) The question is wrong. According to the specification of [Class HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html),

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

As the result depends on the implementation the question should not have been asked or alternatively the answer should have been "None of the above".

2) The actual implementation has changed. The hash used is not the familiar hashCode of `key` but `(h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16)`. This hash is then used for `hash & (SIZE -1)`.