# Why is the initial capacity in HashMap 16 (power of two) and the initial capacity of Hashtable 11(prime number)?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

Please describe the reason if you know. I Googled it, but didn't find well explained answers.

Is it for making index of bucket positive when your `hashCode` is negative?

Comment: Why it is power of two? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352378/why-does-hashmap-require-that-the-initial-capacity-be-a-power-of-two

Comment: @mishadoff Good link, it even anwers the reason for primes in the old `Hashtable`.

Comment: I have already read this post before posting this question but didn't understand much from explanation

Answer (score 9):

For `HashMap`, the index in the array that stores the entries of the Map is calculated this way (where `h` is calculated from  the `hashCode` of the key):

```
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

Where `length` is the length of the array.

This only works when `length` is a power of 2. If `length` wasn't power of 2, you would have to change this code to the less efficient `return h % length`.

Comment: @w00te The code of HashMap is available. You just have to look at the code.

Comment: @w00te Here's one place you can read the code - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: What is wrong if I don't take size as power of two ? What is the benefit of having power of two ?

Comment: @Eran Thanks; I'm surprised it was so well commented in the JDK code :)

Comment: @niiraj874u If you specify an initial HashMap capacity that is not a power of 2, HashMap would change the capacity to the closest power of 2 higher than the capacity you specified. The code above only works when `length` is power of 2.

Comment: @Eran, Thanks for your response. My question is why author of HashMap has decided to keep it power of 2 ? Can you explain me this by some example ?

Comment: @niiraj874u bit-wise and operator (`&`) is faster than modulus operator (`%`). That's it.

Comment: But why we take length 16 why not 15 or 20 ?

Comment: @niiraj874u 15 and 20 are not powers of 2.

Comment: `&` is faster than `%`, but they're equivalent -- _only_ for powers of two.  So using power-of-two table sizes allows you to use `&` instead of `%`, which is faster.

Comment: But why then is `HashTable` different

Comment: @Raedwald HashTable is older than HashMap, and is probably less efficient. I don't know why they chose 11 as the initial capacity, but HashTable class doesn't contain the code that requires a power of two.