# HashMap resizing its table

Tags: java, hashmap

I understand that the size of the HashMap is 16 by default and we also can provide some other  value to it .What if i have initialized the size as 5 with a load factor of 0.8f and then i add the fifth element to it.Does it grow to 10 or 16?Does it jumps to power of two once the threshold breach happens for a non power of 2 value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always best to have a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.resize%28%29):

```
 final Node<K,V>[]  [More ...] resize() {      
         Node<K,V>[] oldTab = table;  
         int oldCap = (oldTab == null) ? 0 : oldTab.length;
         int oldThr = threshold;
         int newCap, newThr = 0;   
         if (oldCap > 0) {   
             if (oldCap >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {   
                 threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;   
                 return oldTab;    
             }    
             else if ((newCap = oldCap << 1) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY &&   
                      oldCap >= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)    
                 newThr = oldThr << 1; // double threshold    
         }    
         else if (oldThr > 0) // initial capacity was placed in threshold    
             newCap = oldThr;
         ...
         // The capacity of the inner data structure is doubled
         Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];
         table = newTab;
         ...
```

So, the current capacity and threshold are doubled upon resize.

**However**, constructing a HashMap object with initial capacity that is not a power of 2 is not possible! Constructor converts the initial capacity into the power of 2:

```
static final int tableSizeFor(int cap) {
     int n = cap - 1;
     n |= n >>> 1;
     n |= n >>> 2;
     n |= n >>> 4;
     n |= n >>> 8;
     n |= n >>> 16;
     return (n < 0) ? 1 : (n >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ? MAXIMUM_CAPACITY: n + 1;
 }

public  [More ...] HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
     ...
     this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
     this.threshold = tableSizeFor(initialCapacity);
}
```

Comment: @ZerekSees Glad to help!

Comment: I wonder why the initial capacity must be the power of 2 ? Would it be a nearest hight number of passed capacity?

Comment: @voipp Because of the easier implementation. With powers of 2, you can easily use bit shifting and other operations on bits, see e.g. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352378/why-does-hashmap-require-that-the-initial-capacity-be-a-power-of-two/8352426