# Determine if num is a power of two in java?

Tags: java, math, methods, algebra, exponent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2)

How could I write a method that would return true if passed in the value 2, 4, 8, 32, 64, and so on?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/600293/1048330

Comment: see bit twiddling hacks (and I'm sure this has been asked before on SO)....

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  Is this homework?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is probably the best way:

```
((value & -value) == value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look at this if you need a fast algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#Fast_algorithm_to_check_if_a_positive_number_is_a_power_of_two