# Determine if number is in the binary sequence 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 etc

Tags: c#, .net, math, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2)

I want to determine if a number is in

`1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
...`

I tried this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    int result = 1;  
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {          
        //Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(result % 2);
        result *= 2;

    }  
}
```

[As you can see](http://rextester.com/MPCN19785) it returns 

`1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...`

How should I efficiently make the above print to be `0` for all of them including 1?

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Is something wrong?

Comment: I know the code works as expected. My question is what code to write to print what **I** expect.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I voted myself to close it. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: For bit fiddling questions, there is often an answer at: http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following expression should be true if `i` is in your sequence.

`(i & (i-1)) == 0)`

http://rextester.com/JRH41036

Comment: that's a really useful site to know about.

Comment: @zapthedingbat, yep. that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Since the first time result is odd, you will get `1`, since right after that you multiply it by 2, you will always get `0`.

You need to print `result` if you want to get the list of powers of 2.

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

A primitive way to do that will be:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    int result = 1;  
    int numToCheck = 141234;
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {          
        if (numToCheck == result) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        result *= 2;
    }  
    if(found) Console.WriteLine("Awesome");
}
```

Comment: What I want is just to determine if `result` is of the binary sequence `1, 2, 4, 8` etc.

Comment: He don't want to write that list i seems, but to know whether any given number is part of that sequence, but that is quite hard to understand given his code.

Comment: You do exactly that. Result is 1 in the first run, then 2, then 4, then 8, then 16, then 32, then 64 and so on.

Comment: What if the number to check is greater than 2^15?

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen - this is a primitive example only, I tried to make the idea clear. not to provide a full implementation.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet - Not to be to critizing here, but he asked for a efficient solution, then you should at least stop searching when you found your answer, and not carry out the full 15 iterations regardless. Adding a break after setting found to true should be in place here :)

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen - you are absolutely right. I meant to add it but forgot :)

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if a number is a power of 2 (including 2^0) by using the following method:

```
public bool IsPowerOfTwo(int x) {
    return (x > 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0)
}
```

[Over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2) you can read why and how this works.

Comment: Woops, true. I got it completely wrong, will update. ... Done.

Comment: I'd use `x>=0`, so all negative numbers get rejected. Or throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if `x<0`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos thanks, modified accordingly. As an alternative you could use a parameter of type `uint`.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
bool IsInBinarySequence( int number ){
  var numbertocheck = 1;
  do{
if( number == numbertocheck ) return true;
numbertocheck *= 2;
  }while( numbertocheck <= number );
  return false;
}
```

This has no specific limit on the number to check, but makes sure it stops checking if the number to check grows larger than the actual number we're trying to decide if is in the binary sequence.

Answer (score 1):

What you is not a test whether the number is in the sequence BUT it is a generator for such numbers... only the print part is containing some sort of a test...

Try this code for a test:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    int result = 0;  
    int numToTest = 0;
    if ( int.TryParse (args[0], out numToTest) )
    {
       result = ((from c in Convert.ToString (numToTest, 2) where c == '1' select c).Count() == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The above code takes a commandline argument and tests it for being in the binary sequence according to the criterion you posted... if so it prints 1, otherwise it prints 0.

Comment: This seems like a good solution :) +1

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but this works ...

```cs
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            var str = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
            var bitCount = str.Count(c => c == '1');
            Console.ForegroundColor = bitCount == 1 ? ConsoleColor.White : ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
            Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + (bitCount == 1));
        }
    }
```

it seems you're actually asking if only one bit in the binary representation of the number is a 1

Comment: Why does color get mixed up into a method checking if a number is in a specific series of numbers?

Comment: because it's an example and i thought it would help highlight when the condition was met

Comment: I didn't read correctly here it seems. Didn't see you setting the console foregroundcolor. Then it seems fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct. 1 0 0 0 0 0 is the correct sequence.
Result is 1 in the first loop. 1 % 2 is 1.
Then result *= 2 gives result the value 2. In the next loop run 2 % 2 = 0. Then result *= 2 is 4. 4%2 is 0. 4 *= 2 is 8. 8 %2 is 0. Since result is always multiplied with 2 it keeps to be in the powers of 2 row and thus als MOD operations with 2 result to 0. So all is fine with that code.

Answer (score 0):

your code will print only Binary sequences. as you are applying MOD 2 . so  either you will get 0 or 1 . so it will be print in Binary Sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean result = false;
Int32 numberToTest = 64;
Int32 limit = 15;

for (int i = 0; i < limit && !result; i++)
{
    if (Math.Pow(2, i).Equals(numberToTest))
    {
        result = true;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number {0} {1} a power of 2.", numberToTest, result ? "is" : "is not"));
```