# Trouble understanding simple algorithm

Tags: php, javascript, algorithm, infinite-loop

sorry for such a specific question but upon looking at the following algorithm written in Javascript

```
  function c(a) {
    if (a < 2) return 2;
    if (a > 4096) return 4096;
    var b = a & (a - 1);
    while (b > 0) {
        a++;
        b = a & (a - 1)
    }
    return a
}
```

I came accross a statement I wasn't sure about. What exactly does `var b = a & (a - 1);` actually do? I was under the assumption it assigned A to B and then subtracted 1 from B, however, if that was the case then wouldn't B never reach 0 (or below 0) resulting in an infinite loop? How can this work?

I ask this because I have attempted to adapt the algorithm to PHP but have hit a wall. It works flawlessly in Javascript, so I know for certain that I'm not understanding what is happening. Here is my attempt in PHP:

```
function c($a) {
    if ($a < 2) return 2;
    if ($a > 4096) return 4096;
        $b = $a 
        $b = ($b - 1);
    while ($b > 0) {
        $a++;
        $b = $a;
        $b -= 1;   
    }
    return $b;
}
```

I can see clearly why it doesn't work but I'm not sure how to change the algorithm to make it work. More or less, I know that I am not adapting the algorithm properly because I don't understand how it works in Javascript.

Either way, please help me! I don't specifically want someone to work out my problem for me but a hint in the right direction would be really great. :(

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That line *clears the lowest set bit* in the value of `a` and assigns the result to `b`.

Example:

```
00010100110101111000
```

Becomes :

```
00010100110101110000
                ^
```

The reason it works is that subtracting one flips all the bits up to and including the least significant bit that was set. All other bits remain unchanged. Using bitwise-and keeps all the bits that have not changed.

```
00010100110101111000  a
00010100110101110111  a-1
00010100110101110000  a & (a-1)
```

---

This loop repeatedly adds one to `a` until clearing one bit of `a` gives zero:

```
b = a & (a - 1);
while (b > 0) {
    a++;
    b = a & (a - 1);
}
```

In other words, it rounds `a` up to the nearest power of 2 in a very inefficient way!

**Related**

- [Bit Twiddling Hacks - Round up to the next highest power of 2](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2)
- [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand entirely now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thats an bitwise operation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 2):

It is the same.

```
function c($a) {
    if ($a < 2) return 2;
    if ($a > 4096) return 4096;
    $b = $a & ($a - 1);
    while ($b > 0) {
       $a++;
       $b = $a & ($a - 1);
    }
    return $b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it returns closest next power of 2. For a power of 2 a & (a-1) returns 0.

Edit:

I just checked this in Java. It does return the next power of 2. When a is 6, it returns 8. When a is 9 it returns 16. If a is 2 it returns 2.

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted but please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2

Comment: Right answer for the unstated question. :) But yes: the original function is quite ineffective way to get next-higher power of two (clamped by 2 and 4096).

Comment: If you look at your numbers in binary form, you'll notice that they contain two ones. But if you try `15` for example, the expression returns `14`. You accidentally picked numbers for which it works.

Comment: Yes, the repeated application of the formula does yield a power of two after a while, but the `a & (a-1)` alone does not.

Comment: That is what I meant. function returns next power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
a & (a-1)
```

will do a bitwise and of a  and (a-1)

in php

```
$b = $a & ($a-1)
```

should work, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
a & (a-1);
```

This statement is doing bit-wise AND operation between `a` and `a-1`. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) link explain you about Bit-wise operations. In PHP you can use `&` operator for AND operation. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) is the link related to PHP.