# Check bitwise flags that cannot co-exist with each other

Tags: c#, java

I have flags

```
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int C = 4;
```

I want to make a check, that only one flag can be specified to a function

```
check(A | B | C) ; // invalid
check(A); // valid
check(B); // valid
check(B | C); // invalid
void check(int flags) {
    // check that if A is specified, then B and C can't
    // check that if B is specified, then A and C can't
    // check that if C is specified, then B and A can't
}
```

How can I achieve this without tons of "if" statements?

Comment: C# and java? did you have the same problem in both languages?

Comment: what do u wanna check exactly?

Comment: Switch is the solution

Comment: If you can choose the values for the flags, I suggest you that when the values are alternative, choose 1,2,3,4,5,... and not 1,2,4,8,16,... 2's powers suggest the user that they are bits and can be OR-ed

Comment: If the flags are exclusive then it could be that your approach is wrong and you actually want to use an enumeration here.

Comment: Steve, I do not care about the language as this is the same in both of them. I just want to get the idea. (Actually I need this for actionscript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but I think it should work:

```
bool check(int flags) {
    int A = 1;
    int B = 2;
    int C = 4;

    return 
        flags == 0 ||
        flags == A ||
        flags == B ||
        flags == C;
}
```

Comment: This seems by far the simplest solution to the question. Assuming that `A,B,C` are defined as constants elsewhere then it's a one-line function.

Answer (score 6):

To set the bit at position *n*, you want to set value *2^n*.

So if you want to check that only one of the flags is specified, then you just want to ask if the number is a power of two.

And here is a question about how to do that: [How to check if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2)

As GrahamS says, you could read the question as saying that exactly one bit must be set (i.e. it can't be zero). So to do that, in addition, check that it's non-zero and that it's less than or equal to C.

Comment: A power of two AND less than or equal to C.

Comment: I think if you try writing that function you'll find it is a lot more complicated that just directly checking the four valid values of `flags` as @MightyPork did.

Comment: Yes that's quite possible. But if you wrote a general function called `hasOneBitSet` you could re-use that. If you are never going to add more than 3 flags then checking them one by one would work. Age old tension between generality and real life. Appropriateness is up to individual circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use use an Enum for your flags, and check if the int value is defined in the enum.

```
enum Flags
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4
}

void Check(int flags)
{
    bool isValid = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Flags), flags);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation with switch:

```
void check(int flags) {
  swicth (flags & (A | B | C)) {
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
    case 0:
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

It will work (in C#) only if `A`, `B` and `C` are literals, i.e. marked with `const`. Otherwise you can do the same with:

```
void check(int flags) {
  int relevantPart = flags & (A | B | C);
  return relevantPart == A || relevantPart == B || relevantPart == C || relevantPart == 0;
}
```

Otherwise use the power-of-two trick (from answer by Joe):

```
void check(int flags) {
  int relevantPart = flags & (A | B | C);
  return (relevantPart & (relevantPart - 1)) == 0;
}
```

I assumed there could be more significant bits than the three least bits, and they were to be ignored. I also assumed that neither `A`, `B`, nor `C` was valid (this is not co-existing in my interpretation).

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment but what GrahamS said was important enough to warrant some elaboration of the point.

Flags are generally used when you specifically want to be able to set multiples. Here is an example of a our task enum

```
namespace Shared.Enumerations
{
    [Flags]
    public enum TaskStatusEnum
    {
        NotSet = 0,
        Open = 1,
        Canceled = 2,
        Complete = 4,
        OnHold = 8,
        Inactive = 32,
        All = Open | Canceled | Complete | OnHold | Inactive
    }
}
```

We do this so we can say give us any task that is open or on hold.

```
 TaskList activeTasks = taskListManager.TaskList.FindAll(target.Name, target.TaskType, (TaskStatusEnum.Open | TaskStatusEnum.OnHold));
```

Of course with a normal enumeration you can only set one thing at a time. You could actually do something like the following.

```
[TestMethod]
public void checkEnumVals()
{
        var ts = TaskStatusTestEnum.Open;
        ts |= TaskStatusTestEnum.OnHold;

        bool matchBoth = false;
        if ((ts & TaskStatusTestEnum.OnHold) == TaskStatusTestEnum.OnHold && (ts & TaskStatusTestEnum.Open) == TaskStatusTestEnum.Open)
           matchBoth = true;

        Assert.IsTrue(matchBoth);
}
```

I wouldn't suggest something like this though.