# What is the most programatically efficient way to determine if a number is a power of 2?

Tags: java, performance, math, recursion, binary

Just a simple of boolean true/false that is very efficient would be nice. Should I use recursion, or is there some better way to determine it?

Comment: Look at its binary representation. A combination of mod and integer division will probably work.

Comment: Some of the C solutions here may be applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2?rq=1

Comment: I'm trying to remember -- something like anding with 1 + the 1's complement.  Anyway, I'm pretty sure it can be done in 4-5 simple operations.

Comment: @Thilo - You simply linked back to this question.

Comment: @Skylion, you should move the accepted answer back to Mitch (ask him to copy my illustrations in); I am only illustrating his answer

Comment: @Thilo What's most efficient in C may not be most efficient in Java. Languages are _not_ created equal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2):

> **Determining if an integer is a power of 2**
>
> ```
> unsigned int v; // we want to see if v is a power of 2
> bool f;         // the result goes here 
>
> f = (v & (v - 1)) == 0;
> ```
>
> Note that 0 is incorrectly considered a power of 2 here. To remedy
>   this, use:
>
> ```
> f = v && !(v & (v - 1));
> ```

Why does this work? An integer power of two only ever has a single bit set. Subtracting 1 has the effect of changing that bit to a zero and all the bits below it to one. `AND`'ing that with the original number will always result in all zeros.

Comment: @MitchWheat The bottom one is not idiomatic. The compiler will throw an error because it will assume you want to assign an `int` to `f`. It should look like this `f = v != 0 && (v & (v - 1)) == 0;`

Answer (score 3):

An Integer power of two will be a 1 followed by one or more zero's

i.e.

```
     Value          value -1 (binary)
   10      2              1
   100     4             11 
   1000    8            111 
   10000  16           1111
```

as **mitch** said

```
  (value & (value-1)) == 0
```

when **value** is a power of 2 (but not for any other number apart from 1 / 0 and 1 is normally regarded as 2 raised to the power of zero).

For mitch's solution, where numbers > 0 that are not powers of 2 i.e.

```
    value              value - 1       V & (v-1)
   1000001             1000000         1000000
   1000010             1000001         1000000
   1000100             1000011         1000000
   1001000             1000111         1000000

   1000011             1000010         1000010
   1000101             1000100         1000100
   1000111             1000110         1000110
```

and never zero.

Subtracting 1 from a number reverses the bits up unto and including the first 1; for power's of two's there is only one '1' so Value & (Value-1) == 0, for other numbers second and subsequent 1's are left un-affected.

**Zero will need to be excluded**

---

Another possible solution (probably slightly slower) is

```
   A & (-A) == A


Powers of 2:
     A      -A 
   00001 & 11111 = 00001
   00010 & 11110 = 00010
   00100 & 11100 = 00100
```

Some other numbers:

```
     A      -A 
   00011 & 11101 = 00001
   00101 & 11011 = 00001
```

Again you need to exclude 0 as well

---

To solve this problem, I did

1. Write the number in binary; you will see that a power of 2 has only a single one in it
2. Fiddle with the various operators / boolean at boolean level and see what works

doing this, I found the following also work:

```
  A & (-A) == A        
 (not A) | (not A + 1) == -1    /* boolean not of a & (a-1) == 0 */
```

Comment: a loop is not required

Comment: Yeah, the original version here was far from the optimal answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether you mean efficient in terms of computation speed, or in terms of lines of code.  But you could try `value == Integer.highestOneBit(value)`.  Don't forget to exclude zero if you need to.

Comment: I mean computing speed.

Comment: I'm afraid, `highestOneBit` is one of the few slow operations, see [this list](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/hotspot-intrinsics/27010/view.html). But you can use `lowestOneBit`, which is much faster (as it uses the hack from the accepted answer).

Comment: Haha, I'll be more careful next time I flip a coin!