# Can a given number be written as a sum of two or more consecutive positive integers?

Tags: java, number-theory

I need to write a method which takes in an `int` and returns `true` if the number can be written as a sum of two or more consecutive positive integers and `false` otherwise.

```
boolean IsSumOfConsecutiveInts(int num)
```

I figured out that all odd numbers (except the number 1) can be written as the sum of 2 consecutive positive integers:

```
return (num > 1 && num % 2 == 1);
```

but this doesn't account for numbers that can be written as the sum of *more than 2* consecutive positive integers (such as `6 == 1 + 2 + 3`).

How can I determine whether a number can be written as a sum of two **or more** consecutive positive integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers are called [Polite Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polite_number).

And, conveniently, the only numbers that *aren't* polite are the powers of 2.

So, that gives us 2 options. We can either determine that a number *is polite*, OR we can determine that it *is not a power of 2*.

I did both; the latter is easier (and more efficient).

1. This determines whether or not a number *is polite*:

   ```
   boolean IsSumOfConsecutiveInts(int num)
   {
       int sumOfFirstIIntegers = 3;
       for (int i = 2; sumOfFirstIIntegers <= num; i++)
       {
           if (i%2 == 0 ? (num%i == i/2) : (num%i == 0))
           {
               return true;
           }
           sumOfFirstIIntegers += i + 1;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

   This one is pretty hard to understand. It took me a while to come up with.

   Basically, `i` is the number of consecutive integers that we are checking;

   `sumOfFirstIIntegers` is equal to the sum of the first `i` integers, so that means that all the numbers that can be expressed as a sum of `i` consecutive integers are greater than or equal to `sumOfFirstIIntegers`.

   The last part that deserves discussing is the boolean statement `i%2 == 0 ? (num%i == i/2) : (num%i == 0)`. Let's look at some examples:

   ```
   i    all sums of i consecutive positive integers
   2    3, 5, 7, 9...
   3    6, 9, 12, 15...
   4    10, 14, 18, 22...
   5    15, 20, 25, 30...
   ```

   There are two cases, but in either case, we can express all possible numbers that are a sum of `i` consecutive integers pretty simply.

   1. When `i` is even, `num` must be equal to `(i * n) + (i / 2)` where `n` is a non-negative integer. This can of course be written as `num % i == i / 2`.
   2. When `i` is odd, `num` must be equal to `i * n`, where `n` is a non-negative integer. Which gives us our second condition `num % i == 0`.

   In addition to these conditions, `num` can not be less than the sum of the first `i` positive integers. Hence, our `for` loop's conditional: `sumOfFirstIIntegers <= num`.
2. This determines whether a number *is not a power of 2*:

   ```
   boolean IsSumOfConsecutiveInts(int num)
   {
       return (num & (num - 1)) != 0;
   }
   ```

   [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600306/2479481) does a good job of explaining why this works.

Note that both of the above solutions have the same result, they are just different ways of thinking about the problem.

Comment: In both 1 and 2, shouldn't `x` be `num`? Could you also rename `y` and `i` to something more descriptive please?

Comment: @KenY-N is correct. Although, there is no reason to rename "i" variable as it is a commonly used for "iteration".. since it is in a loop.