# single ampersand between 2 expressions

Tags: go

I was looking at the Go language source code, module [math/rand](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go). I found there one interesting line

```
if n&(n-1) == 0 { // n is power of two, can mask
```

I'm just curious, what does `n&(n-1)` mean?

I would understand `n && (n-1)`. It would be `AND` operator between 2 boolean expressions. I would understand `&n`. It's address of `n` variable. But what is `n&(n-1)` I cannot figure out.

Full method code:

```
// Int63n returns, as an int64, a non-negative pseudo-random number in [0,n).
// It panics if n <= 0.
func (r *Rand) Int63n(n int64) int64 {
    if n <= 0 {
        panic("invalid argument to Int63n")
    }
    if n&(n-1) == 0 { // n is power of two, can mask
        return r.Int63() & (n - 1)
    }
    max := int64((1 << 63) - 1 - (1<<63)%uint64(n))
    v := r.Int63()
    for v > max {
        v = r.Int63()
    }
    return v % n
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/600306/4466350

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator.

```
// Prints 2, because 3 (0x0011) & 2 (0x0010) = 2 (0x0010)
fmt.Println(3 & 2)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/JFto4ZHUEC