# Create a method to find if a number is a power of 2?

Tags: ruby, methods, fixnum

I have this code to return `true` if `num` is a power of 2.

```
def is_power_of_two?(num)
  result = num.inject(0) {|n1, n2| n2 ** n1}
  if result == num
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

p is_power_of_two?(16)
```

I keep getting an error though. How could I fix and simplify this code?

Comment: Why don't you use log2 function? Should give you back integer if the input is on ^2. Google ```log2 1024```

Comment: Not a Ruby expert but it seems you're using the inject method on an integer instead of on an array

Comment: I tried converting num to an array with `num.to_a` but that wouldnt work for me

Comment: Log2 looks like a good idea, but how could I incorporate it to make sure I'm only getting whole integers as a result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clearly, `n` is a non-negative integer.

**Code**

```
def po2?(n)
  n.to_s(2).count('1') == 1
end
```

**Examples**

```
po2?  0     #=> false
po2?  1     #=> true
po2? 32     #=> true
po2? 33     #=> false
```

**Explanation**

[Fixnum#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) provides the string representation of an integer (the receiver) for a given base. The method's argument, which defaults to 10, is the base. For example:

```
16.to_s     #=> "16" 
16.to_s(8)  #=> "20" 
16.to_s(16) #=> "10"
15.to_s(16) #=>  "f"
```

It's base 2 we're interested in. For powers of 2:

```
 1.to_s(2)  #=>      "1" 
 2.to_s(2)  #=>     "10" 
 4.to_s(2)  #=>    "100" 
 8.to_s(2)  #=>   "1000"
16.to_s(2)  #=>  "10000"
```

For a few natural numbers that are are not powers of 2:

```
 3.to_s(2)  #=>    "11" 
 5.to_s(2)  #=>   "101" 
11.to_s(2)  #=>  "1011"
```

We therefore wish to match binary strings that contain one `1`.

**Another Way**

```
R = /
    \A      # match beginning of string ("anchor")
    10*     # match 1 followed by zero or more zeroes
    \z      # match end of string ("anchor")
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

def po2?(n)
  (n.to_s(2) =~ R) ? true : false
end

po2?(4)  #=> true
po2?(5)  #=> false
```

**One more**

This uses [Fixnum#bit_length](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-bit_length) and [Fixnum#[]](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
def po2?(n)
  m = n.bit_length-1
  n[m] == 1 and m.times.all? { |i| n[i].zero? }
end
```

```
po2?  0     #=> false
po2?  1     #=> true
po2? 32     #=> true
po2? 33     #=> false
```

**And a fourth, perhaps the best**

```
def po2?(n)
  return false if n <= 0
  while n.even?
    n /= 2
  end
  n == 1
end
```

```
po2?  0     #=> false
po2?  1     #=> true
po2? 32     #=> true
po2? 33     #=> false
```

Comment: Could you give some more insight into this answer's syntax? I don't understand it unfortuntely

Comment: Cary, I believe there are no case where a negative number can be power of 2.  A negative N will result in a number less than 1 and a positive non-zero N, will result in a number greater than 1.  If N is a negative number, the use case is invalid and po2? should be false

Comment: @EA, I wrote this more than two years ago. Looking back I'm wondering what I was thinking at the time, but also why it took so long for someone (you) to point out the obvious. Thanks for letting me know. I'll edit.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
def is_power_of_two?(num)
  num != 0 && (num & (num - 1)) == 0
end
```

It is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2) (for C#, but @GregHewgill's explanation applies here as well)

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this, using Ruby's `Math` module.

```
def power_of_two?(n)
  Math.log2(n) % 1 == 0
end
```

Or, if you wanted to be really cool:

```
def power_of_two?(n)
  (Math.log2(n) % 1).zero?
end
```

Some IRB output:

```
2.1.0 :004 > power_of_two?(2)
 => true
2.1.0 :005 > power_of_two?(32768)
 => true
2.1.0 :006 > power_of_two?(65536)
 => true
```

This method assumes that the input is a positive integer.

[Source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Math.html#method-c-log2)

Comment: `(Math.log2(n) % 1).zero?`

Comment: `power_of_two? -3 #=> Math::DomainError: Numerical argument is out of domain - "log2"`.

Comment: Good point; this method assumes that the input is a positive integer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this is to go the other way around than most of the answers here - we can use the number 1 to start and find out if the number is the power of two. Like this:

```
def power_of_two?(num)
  product = 1

  while product < num
    product *= 2
  end
  product == num
end
```

We start with 1. Then we multiply the 1 by 2, and keep multiplying by 2 until the product is larger than `num` (`product < num`). Once we hit that condition, we stop, exit the loop, and check if it's equal to `num` (`product == num`). If it is, the `num` is the power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments above, you were getting errors because you're trying to use the `inject` method on a non-iterable (an int). Here's a solution using the suggested `log2`

```
def is_power_of_two?(num)
  result = Math.log2(num)
  result == Integer(result)
end
```

Note: will fail with very big numbers close to binaries (like 2 ^ 64 - 1). A foolproof version (but slower) would be:

```
def is_power_of_two?(num)
  while (num % 2 == 0 and num != 0)
    num /= 2
  end
  num == 1
end
```

Please comment any improvements that any of you may find.

Comment: Of course we never use `conditional_statement ? true : false` because `conditional_statement` by definition will itself evaluate as `true` or `false`.

Comment: Yeah i was playing it safe and using OP's code as a base since it's my very first attempt at Ruby. Then realized how pointless that `if` was.

Comment: Feel free to update your code to improve that.  So it doesn't get mentioned again, or so someone else doesn't have to edit it. :)  And welcome to Ruby!

Comment: Not a code review site, of course, but at this point, I wouldn't even use the local variable result.  Just compare the two values directly, and it will return true or false, and is simple enough to read and understand.

Comment: @vgoff you should come check us out over at CR, maybe drop by [The Second Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that uses recursion:

```
def power_of_2?(number)
 return true if number == 1
 return false if number == 0 || number % 2 != 0
 power_of_2?(number / 2)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest -- but maybe a little long -- way of doing what you need to do is just writing this recursive method like so:

```
def power_of_two?(number)
    continue = true
    if number == 1
        return true
    end
    if number % 2 != 0
        return false
    else
        while continue == true do
            if number.to_f / 2.0 == 2.0
                continue = false
                return true
            else
                if number % 2 != 0
                    continue = false 
                    return false
                else
                    number /= 2
                    continue = true
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

One is a power of two (2^0), so it first checks if the number given is 1. If not, it checks if it is odd, because 1 is the only odd number that is a power of two.

If it is odd it returns false and moves on to the else statement. It will check if the number divided by 2 is two, because then it would obviously be a power of 2. It does this as a float, because 5/2 in Ruby would return 2.

If that is false, it then again checks if the number is odd -- unnecessary on the first round, necessary after that. If the number is not odd, it will divide the number by two and then do the loop another time.

This will continue until the program resolves itself by getting 2 or any odd number, and returns true or false, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this one in a bootcamp application prep.  I'm not a math person and don't understand a few of these methods, so I wanted to submit a common sense approach for people like me.  this requires little knowledge of math, except to know a number to the second power will be the result of some number multiplied by itself.

```
def is_power_of_two?(num)
  num.times  {|n| return true if (n+1) * (n+1) == num}
  false
end
```

this method counts up to the num variable starting at 1 and returns true if (any of those numbers in the sequence multiplied by itself)  is equal to num & if num is not 0 (more on that below).

example: 
num = 9

```
1 * 1 == 9 #=> false
2 * 2 == 9 #=> false
3 * 3 == 9 #=> true
```

true is returned and method is finished running.

the #times method requires an integer > 0, so this edge case is "handled" by virtue of the fact that #times does nothing with "0" as the variable and returns false when outside of the #times iteration.

Comment: while this looked elegant to me at first, I realize now that it's inefficient as all get out, as it goes through potentially a lot more numbers  than needed  to get your answer.   looked good.

Answer (score 0):

```
def power_of_two?(num)
  num.to_s(2).scan(/1/).length == 1
end
```