# C# generic function implementation of isPowerOf2<T>(T x)

Tags: c#, generics

In C++ I routinely use this templated function...

```
template<typename T>
bool isPowerOf2 (T x) // returns nonzero if x is a power-of-2
{
  return x && ((x & (~x + 1)) == x);
}
```

...and I'm trying to implement the same thing in C#. So here's the best I can come up with:

```
public class Utils
{
   // ...

   public static bool isPowerOf2<T>(T x) // returns true if x is a power-of-2
   {
      return (x != 0) && ((x & (~x + 1)) == x);
   }
}
```

But Visual Studio complains that `error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'int'` and `error CS0023: Operator '~' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'`.

If I remove the generic stuff & just make it "`public static bool isPowerOf2(int x)`", it works fine (just like in [various implementations here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/600293/1245420)), but I'd like the implementation to be generic so it would work on any integer type.

Comment: I'm not a C# expert, but I think the answer is no, you can't do it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32664/3973077

Answer (score 5):

This is a good illustration of why C# generics are not C++ templates. C# must be able to compile code without knowing `T`, while C++ could postpone compiling until the type of `T` is known. This lets C++ figure out how to perform `~`, `+`, `&`, and so on.

The simplest approach with C# is to make multiple overloads for types that you plan to use with the function. This results in a small amount of code duplication, but it reads much better than other options, such as generating code dynamically with LINQ expressions.

If performance is not critical, you could also use `Convert.ToInt64`:

```
bool isPowerOf2 (object obj) {
    var x = Convert.ToInt64(obj);
    return x && ((x & (~x + 1)) == x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`C#` does static type checking, this can be bypassed declaring [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type. You can still do what you want to do having input parameter is of type `dynamic`. Please note `~` works only on integers, fails for float and double.

```
public class Utils
{
   // ...

   public static bool isPowerOf2(dynamic x) 
   {
      return (x != 0) && ((x & (~x + 1)) == x);
   }
}
```

Check this [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nKgSBd)

Comment: dynamic can accept literally anything. COM object or even null.

Comment: That's correct, one should add defensive coding for such a cases.