# Checking if a double is a power 2

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to check if a double is a power of 2. This is my code so far:

```
double x = Double.longBitsToDouble(
    Double.doubleToRawLongBits(n) & Double.doubleToRawLongBits(n - 1)
);
```

I used the following formula to find if the number is a power of 2:

```
n & (n - 1) == 0
```

But its not working.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2

Comment: Aren't all Java `double` values powers of 2? Since `double` is an IEEE-754 **binary** double-precision value? Or do you mean a whole number power of 2?

Comment: You should understand why the trick is supposed to work, and what the bits in a `double` represent in order to understand why that trick **won't work with `double`**.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Obviously he means a whole-number power.  I mean, any positive number could be expressed as some irrational power of 2.

Comment: @DM: I don't think it's obvious. If you have to invoke irrational numbers to make it obvious, I don't think it's obvious at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Irrational numbers are exactly why it is obvious.  But if you can tell me what (rational) power of two 3 is, I might consider conceding the point.

Comment: Since all `double` values are only coincidentally accurate, obviously the assertion that "every `double` is a power of `2`" implies "to within one ULP". So the question of irrational numbers is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with big numbers you can use the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class:

```
public boolean isPowerOfTwo(BigInteger n) {
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return (n.and(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for 0.5, which is an integer power of 2.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is working with very large numbers, then Oleksandr's answer is better, but if you really want to check whether a `double` is an even power of two, you can just check if the mantissa is zero:

```
(Double.doubleToLongBits(n) & 0x000fffffffffffffL) == 0
```

To be more robust, you'll want to handle the edge cases for non-normalized numbers (infinities, NaNs, denormals, and perhaps decide on whether zeroes should return true), but those are normally edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for all cases, though whether infinity is considered a power of 2 may be application specific.

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(double val) {
    if (val <= 0.0 || Double.isNaN(val))
        return false; // You can't raise 2 to a power and get a negative number or zero.
    if (Double.isInfinite(val))
        return false; // Arguable assumption. val is bigger than MAX_VALUE but we don't really know if it's a power of 2 or not.
    long significand = Double.doubleToLongBits(val) & 0x000f_ffff_ffff_ffffL;
    if (val >= Double.MIN_NORMAL)
        return significand==0; // only the hidden 1 remains
    else
        return (Long.bitCount(significand) == 1); // denormalized, no hidden one, power of two only if exactly one bit in significand is set
}
```