# Is there a trick to testing if a non-specific bit is set anywhere in an int?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I want to test whether any single bit is set in a C `int`. I don't care which bit it is.

Equivalent to

```
if (1 == count_bits (n))
```

I'm curious if there is a non-looping algorithm for this which does not require special hardware support.

Comment: Check if `n` is *non-zero*?

Comment: Your text might indicate, that you are looking for `a == 0`, but your code snippet indicates, that you want to check if *exactly one* bit is set. Can you please specify it?

Comment: In an `int`? How do you want negative values handled?

Answer (score 5):

If only one bit is set, then the number is a power of two.

```
unsigned int IsPowerOfTwoNoLoop(unsigned int input)
{
    unsigned int temp = input;
    if(0 == input)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    temp -= 1;
    /*Example of the logic:*/
    /*  0100 (4 DEC) - 1 = 0011
        0011 & 0100 = 0000 
    */
    if (temp & input) /* if not zero - not pow of two */
    {
        printf("%u Is NOT the power of two !\n", input);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%u Is the power of two !\n", input);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: For the explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2#600306

Comment: I would suggest to use `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int`. Why don't you accept any digit and reinterpret them as an unsigned value in your function?

Comment: Review: it would be much clearer (=better) to return `bool` from this function.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to convert to an unsigned type.

Then we are simply testing whether we have an exact power of two.

We can use a simple observation that these are the only non-zero numbers that have no bits in common with `n-1`:

```
bool is_power_of_two(unsigned int n)
{
    return n && ! (n & (n-1));
}
```

Comment: "This code falsely returns one when input is zero. – Eric Postpischil"

Comment: Oops - I mistakenly thought I'd taken that into account, and failed.