# Generic single flag enumeration for bitmask enums

Tags: c#, enums, ienumerable, bitmask

I'm working on a codebase with several bit flags enums which look something like this

```
public enum BitMask
{
    None = 0,

    OptionA = 1 << 0,
    OptionB = 1 << 1,

    OptionAandB = OptionA | OptionB,

    All = ~0
}
```

I can iterate over all enum values using this

```
public IEnumerable<T> EnumValues<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
}
```

I'm looking for a generic way to iterate over single flag values only, in this case, `OptionA` and `OptionB`. **Not** `None`, `OptionAandB`, `All`. I can cast to `long` and detect single flags as they are a power of two, a quick search on here suggests this

```
public bool IsPowerOfTwo(long val)
{
    return (val != 0) && ((val & (val-1)) == 0) ;
}
```

Nongeneric version works fine

```
public IEnumerable<BitMask> SingleFlagBitMaskValues()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(BitMask))
               .Cast<BitMask>()
               .Where(e => IsPowerOfTwo((long)e));
}
```

But the generic version doesn't compile because it doesn't like the cast to `long`

```
public IEnumerable<TEnum> SingleFlagEnumValues<TEnum>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
        .Cast<TEnum>()
        .Where(e => IsPowerOfTwo((long)e));
}
```

Any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Convert.ToInt64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint64?view=netframework-4.8) due to its many overloads:

```
public IEnumerable<TEnum> SingleFlagEnumValues<TEnum>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
        .Cast<TEnum>()
        .Where(e => IsPowerOfTwo(Convert.ToInt64(e)));
}
```

As suggested in comments, here's for optimisation:

```
static class SingleFlagCache<TEnum>
{
    internal static TEnum[] values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
        .Cast<TEnum>()
        .Where(e => IsPowerOfTwo(Convert.ToInt64(e))).ToArray();
}
public static IEnumerable<TEnum> SingleFlagEnumValues<TEnum>()
    => SingleFlagCache<TEnum>.values;
```

Comment: this should indeed work, and it is possibly the *least ugly* of the available workarounds for the limitations of generics, but: it is *really* very inefficient - lots of boxing and type testing; IMO, this would strongly benefit from a static hoist - possibly something like https://gist.github.com/mgravell/4e684204899b4ef3a33bb1c495b4fbe2

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell, I agree. Feel free to edit that into this answer if you'd like to :).

Comment: Added suggested optimisation and accepted answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative version for comparison:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEnum> SingleFlagEnumValues<TEnum>() where TEnum: struct, Enum
{
    var type = typeof(TEnum);

    foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(type))
    {
        if (IsPowerOfTwo(value))
            yield return (TEnum)(object)value;
    }
}
```

(My timings indicate that this is about 1.5 times faster than using `Convert.ToInt64(e)`, but for such a fast operation this likely doesn't matter. It still does casting anyway.)