# PossibleSums in Map with given list of doubles or double array in java 8

Tags: java

below code give all possible sums for given double array , how to do this same with java8 streams and producing result in `Map<Integer,Double[]> like below

```
(0,[15],[0.55])
```

code without map implementation:

```
public class PossibleDoubleSums {
    public static void getAllSums(double []arr, double startingValue, int pos  ) {
   
        for (int i = pos; i < arr.length; i++) {
            
            double currentValue = startingValue + arr[i];
           System.out.println(currentValue+"");
           
            getAllSums(arr, currentValue, i + 1);
        }
        
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {          
        double arr[] = {15.00, 0.55,25.00, 7.00};
        getAllSums(arr, 0, 0 ); // Test array
    
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good problem to do with stream, I mean recursive problem.

Comment: And don't know why you need Map as List serve all what you need.

Comment: Eklavya can I have list version?

Comment: Possible to store each current value as object in list?

Comment: can you please provide the expected output for your given code snippet? The given `(0,[15],[0.55])` is unclear

Comment: I want to store as list of double objects not just current value , current value is sum of different possibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Returning the possible sums

```java
class Solution {
    public static List<Double> solve(double[] arr) {
        return IntStream.range(0, 1 << arr.length).boxed()
            .filter(n -> (n & (n - 1)) != 0)
            .map(n -> IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                .filter(i -> ((n >> i) & 1) == 1)
                .mapToDouble(i -> arr[i])
                .sum())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
final double[] arr = { 15.00, 0.55, 25.00, 7.00 };
System.out.println(solve(arr));
// Outputs [15.55, 40.0, 25.55, 40.55, 22.0, 7.55, 22.55, 32.0, 47.0, 32.55, 47.55]
```

### Returning the possible pairs

```java
class Solution {
    public static List<Double[]> solve(double[] arr) {
        return IntStream.range(0, 1 << arr.length).boxed()
            .filter(n -> (n & (n - 1)) != 0)
            .map(n -> IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed()
                .filter(i -> ((n >> i) & 1) == 1)
                .map(i -> arr[i])
                .toArray(Double[]::new))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
final double[] arr = { 15.00, 0.55, 25.00, 7.00 };
        
final List<Double[]> result = solve(arr);
for (Double[] resultArr : result) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArr));
}
```

#### Output

```
[15.0, 0.55]
[15.0, 25.0]
[0.55, 25.0]
[15.0, 0.55, 25.0]
[15.0, 7.0]
[0.55, 7.0]
[15.0, 0.55, 7.0]
[25.0, 7.0]
[15.0, 25.0, 7.0]
[0.55, 25.0, 7.0]
[15.0, 0.55, 25.0, 7.0]
```

### Explanation

Let's break it down using `{15.00, 0.55, 25.00, 7.00}` as input array:

1. `IntStream.range(0, 1 << arr.length)` creates a stream of values from 0 until `1 << arr.length`. The expression `1 << n` is the same as `Math.pow(n, 2)`, so `1 << arr.length` will be equal to 16.

The stream now is `IntStream({0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 12, 13, 14, 15})`.

2. `boxed()` converts this `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>`. This allows us to convert it to a `List<Integer>` in the end.

The stream now is `Stream<Integer>({0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 12, 13, 14, 15})`.

3. `filter(n -> (n & (n - 1)) != 0)` removes all power-of-2 elements from the stream including 0 ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600306/9997212)). Why is this? Let's take a look at the binary representation of the current stream:

   ```
   {0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, 0110, 0111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111}
   ```

   Now assign every bit to its respective array element: the number `0110` correspond to the elements `{0.55, 25.00}`, the number `0001` correspond to the elements `{7.00}` and the number `1111` correspond to all elements (`{15.00, 0.55, 25.00, 7.00}`) since all bits are set.

   Following your test cases, we cannot include the input numbers in the output array (for example, neither 15.0, 0.55, 25 or 7 should be in the output array). Therefore, we cannot include the numbers which contain a single bit (such as `0001` or `0100`). These numbers are powers of 2, therefore we must remove them.

The stream now is `Stream<Integer>({3, 5, 6, 7, ..., 12, 13, 14, 15})`.

4. `map(...)` maps the elements of this stream to another type. For each element `n` (assuming `n` is equal to 6),

   1. `IntStream.range(0, arr.length)` creates a stream from 0 until 4.

   The substream now is `IntStream({0, 1, 2, 3})`.

   2. `filter(i -> ((n >> i) & 1) == 1)` keeps only the indexes of the bits which are 1.

   The substream now is `IntStream({1, 2})`. Note that `n` is equal to 6, whose binary representation is `0110`. Since the mid-two bits are set, the mid-two elements in the input array will be kept.

   3. `mapToDouble(i -> arr[i])` maps each bit to its respective element in the input array.

   The substream now is `IntStream({0.55, 25.00})`.

   4. `sum()` sums all elements from this stream.

   The result is `25.55`.
5. `collect(Collectors.toList())` will repeat step 4 for all element in this stream, returning a `List<Double>`.

The result is `[15.55, 40.0, 25.55, 40.55, 22.0, 7.55, 22.55, 32.0, 47.0, 32.55, 47.55]`.

Comment: Wow ! I appreciate your effort and nice explanation about bitmasking.

Comment: very nice explanation seeing beauty of java 8 or more

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you want to use Stream. It's not the right context where you can use the Stream.
I suggest you can simply create a Map and put the values in it

```
public class PossibleDoubleSums {
    
    static int count = 0;
    
    public static void getAllSums(Map<Integer,Double> imaps, double []arr, double startingValue, int pos  ) {
   
        for (int i = pos; i < arr.length; i++) {
            double currentValue = startingValue + arr[i];
            imaps.put(count++, currentValue);
            getAllSums(imaps, arr, currentValue, i + 1);
        }
        
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Map<Integer,Double> imaps = new HashMap<>();
        double arr[] = {15.00, 0.55,25.00, 7.00};
        getAllSums(imaps, arr, 0, 0 ); // Test array
        System.out.println(imaps);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nagaraj : i don’t want this , current is value is sum of different index’s of double array . I think I have asked question wrongly instead of Double , I want to store Double []

Comment: The expected output in your first code snippet is not a Map<Integer, Double[]>, it's a Map<Integer, Double>.