# Check whether a given number is a power of two

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a function which returns a value 1 if the number entered is a power of two, else it returns a value 0.

```
function val = func_1(num)
   while not(num == 1)
      if num%2~=0
         val=0;
         break
      end
      num=num/2;
      val=1;
   end
end
```

But unfortunately, the function always return a value 1. Is there any error in the algorithm or the code? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Unless you really want to do it by hand, you can use `num==2^nextpow2(num)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab, `%` is the comment character. Everything from that point onwards until the end of the line is ignored. This means that this line `if num%2~=0` is not doing what you think it does.

Instead, use the `mod` function. [link](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html). In this case, the line in question becomes `if mod(num, 2)~=0`.

On a separate note, I suspect there is a much more efficient way of doing this. See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2).

Comment: Thanks @RPM. I missed that comments are made using `%`.