# Inserting elements into indexes that are the powers of 2 [Prolog]

Tags: list, prolog

I have to insert an element into a list on the positions that are powers of 2

e.g. in the list

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I should insert an element `E = 0` after the `first` element, then the `third`, then the `7th`, etc. so the resulting list would be

```
R = [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8]
```

I tried using the predefined predicate `nth1/4` to add an element into a list at a position P and then increase the position P by multiplying it with 2

```
%empty list
ins_aux(_, [], _, _, []).
%if the position is even, add the element and then multiply P by 2 
%and add a value K which is incremented at every step to get the next position 
ins_aux(E, L, P, K, Res) :- 0 is mod(P, 2), !, 
                         nth1(P, Res, E, L), 
                         P1 is (P*2)+K,
                         K1 is K+1,
                         ins_aux(E, Res, P1, K1, Res).
%if the position is odd, add the element to the list 
ins_aux(E, L, P, K, Res) :- nth1(P, Res, E, L),
                         P1 is P+1,
                         ins_aux(E, Res, P1, K, Res).
```

My issue is that this always outputs `false.` I am clearly doing something wrong it's just that I don't know what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use `nth1` in `ins_aux`? This makes things ... unnecessarily quadratic:)

Here's how you could do it:

```
ins_aux([],_,_,[]).
ins_aux([E|Es],X,I,[E|Rs0]) :-
   (  I /\ (I-1) =\= 0
   -> Rs0 = Rs1                  % I is not a power of two
   ;  Rs0 = [X|Rs1]              % I is     a power of two
   ),
   I1 is I + 1,
   ins_aux(Es,X,I1,Rs1).
```

Sample queries using Scryer Prolog:

```
?- ins_aux([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],0,2,Rs).
   Rs = [1,0,2,3,0,4,5,6,7,0,8].

?- ins_aux([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],0,2,Rs).
   Rs = [a,0,b,c,0,d,e,f,g,0,h].
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the solution, but uhh... I did not know about this /\ operator... is it like pow()?

Comment: See https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f((/%5C)/2) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2

Comment: Are these cuts really necessary? Would not a clean if-then-else be preferable, after all `(=:=)/2` ensures with instantiation errors that the expression and thus `I` is sufficiently instantiated.

Comment: And speaking of efficiency, note that the second case is much more frequent than the first....

Comment: One more: 1 is a power of two. Is it not?

Comment: @false. It is. But this is about the index, not about the element itself. I think the added query should make that clearer.

Comment: The 1st element is the (2⁰)th. Is it not?

Comment: @false. Yes. `[1,x,2,x,3,4,x,5,6,7,8,x,...]` vs `[1,x,2,3,x,4,5,6,7,x,8,...]`. Arguably, the former one is the right one, but the OP wanted the latter.