# Dynamically increase dimension of array of struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

i want a dynamic array of my `struct Data` to contais the element of the file.I don't know the dimension of the file before so i need a dynamic array to cointains it. Should i use an array of struct or do you suggest a linked list?(the purpose is to create a quick sort and sort the element of the file) Why doesn't print anything? I did something wrong with malloc e realloc?

manager.h:

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Data
{
    int id;
    char field1[50];
    int field2;
    float field3;
};

extern struct Data* records; 

int readFile();
#endif
```

managaer.c

```
#include "manager.h"

struct Data* records; 

int readFile(){
    FILE *file = fopen("records.csv","r");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    records = malloc(sizeof(struct Data));
    int num=0;
    do{
        fscanf(file,"%d,%49[^,],%d,%f\n",&records[num].id,records[num].field1,&records[num].field2,&records[num].field3);
        num++;
        records = realloc(records,num*sizeof(struct Data));

    }while(num<5);

    fclose(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d %s %d %f",records[i].id,records[i].field1,records[i].field2,records[i].field3);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is 5 the maximum number of items? In this case, why don't malloc space for 5 items from the beginning? Also, you need to initialize `num` to 0 not to 1, otherwise you write to an offset that is not reserved yet in `fscanf(file,"%d,%49[^,],%d,%f\n",&records[num] ...`, then you call `realloc` with `num + 1` elements.

Comment: 5 is only a try to test the dynamic allocation. 
And yes, if i only do a malloc for 5 item it works, but i need to increase dynamically cause the file is much bigger

Comment: Then you want `while (fscanf(...) == 4) { ... }` where 4 is the number of elements to scan instead of `do { ... } while (num < 5)`

Comment: In your edit, you initilize `num` to 0 but you forget to `realloc` with `num + 1`, ok, let me write an answer ...

Comment: `while (fscanf(...) == 4) { ... }` should give me the number of element in a row, in this case `num` indicate the number of row read not the element inside in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

To read the whole file you can loop while `fscanf` returns the number of elements to scan, since you have 4 columns per row:

```
while (fscanf(file,"%d,%49[^,],%d,%f\n", ...) == 4)
{
}
```

You also need to take care of the value of `num` on each iteration, switch to:

```
size_t num = 0;
while (fscanf(file,"%d,%49[^,],%d,%f\n", ...) == 4) // you can avoid the "\n"
{
    num++;
    records = realloc(records, (num + 1) * sizeof(struct Data));
}
```

Notice `num + 1` instead of `num`, otherwise you end up writing to a non existent offset in the next iteration when you call `fscanf`. Also prefer `size_t` over `int` when dealing with dynamic memory.

Comment: ok, now it works,thanks. But this is a good solution to read a file of 3minlion rows of data or it's better to do anything else?

Comment: Nops, is not a good idea to call `realloc` 3 million times, reserve space for a number of elements that is a power of 2 and call again `realloc` when the size is exhausted multiplyng the size by 2, you have an example on how to do this here: https://github.com/davranfor/c/blob/master/dynarray/dynarray.c#L32

Comment: `void* extendArray(void *array){
    return realloc(array,sizeof *array * 2);
}`

Comment: Something like that could be use to double the size?

Comment: Nops, you want `sizeof *array * (num * 2)` but call `realloc` only when `num` is a power of 2, as shown in the link.

Comment: `num++;
 if(num%2==0){records = realloc(records, 2*(num + 1) * sizeof(struct Data)); }`

Changing like that the code in the while?

Comment: No, that's not correct, 6 % 2 is 0 but 6 is not a power of 2. Powers of 2 are 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2